# Unable to recover a file in Git

Tags: git, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore a deleted file in a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)

I have two branches in my Git, *master and newFeature*.
At the branch *newFeature*, I removed the fileA physically first in terminal and then in Git by

```
git rm fileA
```

Subsequently, I run

```
git add .
git commit
```

Right now, I need the **fileA** again. 
I had the idea that I can get it back, by simply switching to the branch *master*.
I was apparently wrong, since I cannot find the **fileA**.

**How can I get the fileA back with Git?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to find where you have last version of `fileA`. You can use "git log -p" or "git whatchanged" to check when it was deleted, or you can use "git ls-files <*revision*> -- fileA" to check if file is present in given commit, where '<*revision*>' can be *master* or *newFeature^* (*newFeature^* means parent of *newFeature*).

Then you need to check it out, either using

```
$ git checkout <revision> -- fileA
```

or redirect "git show" output

```
$ git show <revision>:fileA > fileA
```

Don't forget to add file to git (if needed)!

Answer (score 3):

Create a tag or branch at the commit before you deleted fileA, check it out, copy fileA somewhere else, then checkout the `newFeature` branch again. The rest should be pretty simple.

Comment: You also may git checkout <commit hash> without creating the branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
@titan:~$ cd /tmp/
@titan:/tmp$ mkdir x
@titan:/tmp$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/.git/
@titan:/tmp$ echo a > a
@titan:/tmp$ git add a
@titan:/tmp$ git ci -m a
Created initial commit c835beb: a
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
@titan:/tmp$ git rm a
rm 'a'
@titan:/tmp$ git ci -m b
Created commit de97fae: b
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 a
@titan:/tmp$ git whatchanged 
commit de97fae7a72375ffa192643836ec8273ff6f762b
Date:   Wed Mar 11 17:35:57 2009 +0100

    b

:100644 000000 7898192... 0000000... D  a

commit c835beb7c0401ec27d00621dcdafd366d2cfdcbe
Date:   Wed Mar 11 17:35:51 2009 +0100

    a

:000000 100644 0000000... 7898192... A  a
@titan:/tmp$ git show 7898192
a
@titan:/tmp$ git show 7898192 > a
@titan:/tmp$
```