# how to restore deleted file

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore a deleted file in a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)

How do I restore a file I accidentally removed from my `git` repository?  I know this is a trivial question, but I haven't found the answer in the documentation.

Comment: Did you commit after delete? If not you can commit and checkout the file back again.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`git checkout <commit> <path>`

Commits may be specified directly by SHA1, or via a branch or tag. Make sure that the  represents the state of the repository when the deleted file was still present. If the commit argument is omitted, the currently checked out commit (HEAD) will be used.

Comment: I figured it was something trivially simple.  I guess I interpreted the documentation as referring to complete trees rather than individual files.  Thanks.

Comment: It *does* refer to complete trees *unless* you also give a file name. :)

Comment: this removed all my modifications unstaged. Thank you.

Comment: Too can see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39296006/5869837