# What does the caret (^) character mean in Git?

Tags: git

I saw an [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo/1113140#1113140) here that helps restore a deleted file in git.

The solution was

```
git checkout <deleting_commit>^ -- <deleted_file_path>
```

What does the caret character (`^`) do? I’ve seen it elsewhere doing very useful things in git. It’s magical. Someone please spoil it for me and tell me what it does?

Comment: FYI on windows: ^ doesn't work as expected in DOS shell. Use git bash shell and then it works.

Comment: That didn't even occur to me when I've attempted to use it (guessing on what it means). The caret (`^`) is the escape character in cmd.exe. Every time I've tried to use it to see if it would be helpful I was actually passing nothing, which explains why the results were never different. >_> Stupid cmd.exe. You can escape it by doubling it or quoting it:

`git log master^^` or `git log "master^"`

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`HEAD^` means the first parent of the tip of the current branch.

Remember that git commits can have more than one parent. `HEAD^` is short for `HEAD^1`, and you can also address `HEAD^2` and so on as appropriate.

You can get to parents of any commit, not just `HEAD`. You can also move back through generations: for example, `master~2` means the grandparent of the tip of the master branch, favoring the first parent in cases of ambiguity. These specifiers can be chained arbitrarily
, *e.g.*, `topic~3^2`. See related answer to [What’s the difference between `HEAD^` and `HEAD~` in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222920/123109)

For the full details, see the [“Specifying Revisions”](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions/) section of `git rev-parse --help`.

Comment: But then, on linear history, why does `HEAD^^^` return the third older commit  i.e. it is equivalent to `HEAD~~~`?

Comment: @Vorac For linear history, yes.

Answer (score 27):

It means "parent of". So `HEAD^` means "the parent of the current HEAD". You can even chain them together: `HEAD^^` means "the parent of the parent of the current HEAD" (i.e., the grandparent of the current HEAD), `HEAD^^^` means "the parent of the parent of the parent of the current HEAD", and so forth.

Comment: This answer is not right for merge commits. If `HEAD` is following a merge commit, then `HEAD^` means the *first parent* of `HEAD`, and `HEAD^^` (or `HEAD^2`) means the *second parent* of `HEAD`. In a merge commit, the second parent of `HEAD` is not the same thing as the parent of the parent of `HEAD`. See [Ancestry References](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) in the Git manual.

Comment: @bhagerty: That is wrong. While `HEAD^2` does indeed indicate the _second parent_ of `HEAD`, `HEAD^2` and `HEAD^^` are _not_ synonymous. Multiple carets do refer to commits in relation to the _first parent_, so just as `HEAD^^` refers in general to the grandparent of `HEAD`, `HEAD^^` the grandparent of parent of the first commit of `HEAD` when `HEAD` is a merge commit; likewise, `HEAD^2^` is the parent of the _second_ parent.

Comment: Thanks, @mipadi. I assume you are correct, though the documentation doesn't come close to making this clear. As far as I can tell, `HEAD~~` and `HEAD~2` are synonymous, so by analogy, I expected the number operator to work similarly with the caret. From what you are saying, it does not. That is unfortunate.

Answer (score 27):

The `^` (caret) can also be used when [specifying ranges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_ranges).

> To exclude commits reachable from a commit, a **prefix ^ notation** is
>   used. E.g. ^r1 r2 means commits reachable from r2 but exclude the ones
>   reachable from r1.
>
> **<rev>**
>
> Include commits that are reachable from (i.e. ancestors of) .
>
> **^<rev>**
>
> Exclude commits that are reachable from (i.e. ancestors of) .

Comment: yep, this was exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a visual explanation. Suppose you have a history like so:

```
                      master  
  ... <- B <- C <- D
             /
... <- E <- F
              feature
```

When feature was merged into master, `C` was created with two ancestors. Git assigns these ancestors numbers. The mainline ancestor `B` is assigned 1 and the feature ancestor `F` is assigned 2.

Thus `C^1` refers to `B` and `C^2` refers to `F`. `C^` is an alias for `C^1`.

You would only ever use `<rev>^3`. if you had performed a merge of three branches.

Comment: is that actually legal? can a merge commit contain three parents?

Comment: A merge commit can have N parents. The only distinction between a regular commit and a merge is the number of parents.

Comment: After going through this comment, reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git/2222920#2222920 gives more clarity

Answer (score 9):

The caret refers to the parent of a particular commit. E.g. `HEAD^` refers to the parent of the current HEAD commmit. (also, `HEAD^^` refers to the grandparent).

Answer (score 5):

> OP: What does the **caret (^)** character mean in Git?

#### *The ^ (Caret) and ~ (Tilde) selectors*

The difference between `HEAD^` (Caret) and `HEAD~` (Tilde) is how they traverse history backwards from a specified starting point, in this particular case `HEAD`.

##### Tilde ~

`<rev>~[<n>]` = select `<n>th` generation ancestor, following only first* parents

##### Caret ^

`<rev>^[<n>]` = select `<n>th` parent of first generation ancestors

**First parent is always the left hand side of the merge, e.g. the commit on the branch that got merged into.*

##### Joining ~ and ^ together

As seen in the illustration below the two selectors **~** and **^** can be used in combination. Also note that instead of using `HEAD` as a starting point, any regular reference can be used such as a ***branch***, ***tag*** or even a ***commit hash***.

Further more, depending on what ancestor is intended to be selected **^** and **~** can be used interchangeably as seen below in the table.

[image: Illustration of relative references in Git]

**Source:** A thorough rundown can be found in [this](https://blog.git-init.com/relative-vs-absolute-references-in-git/) blog post on the subject.

Comment: This is a near-perfect explanation and diagram. The only minor comment I have relates to the letters in the diagram. I think it would be easier to understand if the letters went backwards in the alphabet. The way you have it now, the flow of the letters is contrary to the flow of time, which is counterintuitive. It's clear from your arrow of time that C came before B came before A in time. But this is not how we expect the alphabet to work.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @bhagerty ! And great suggestion, I'll definitely look into making the change. Indeed, it's a bit counter intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

The carat represents a commit offset (parent). So for instance, `HEAD^` means "one commit from HEAD" and `HEAD^^^` means "three commits from HEAD".

Answer (score 4):

The (^) gets the parent source of the command i.e. HEAD^ will get the parent of HEAD.

Answer (score 2):

Greg Bacon gave a great link, but it's pretty dense. The Git introductory docs online also introduce revision and range specifiers:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

Comment: This link might be closer to the location intended.  http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References