# Show diff between commits

Tags: git, git-diff

I am using Git on [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx).

I have made some commits to my master.

However, I want to get the difference between these commits. All of them are on my master branch.

For example:

```
commit dj374
made changes

commit y4746
made changes

commit k73ud
made changes
```

I want to get the difference between k73ud and dj374. However, when I did the following I couldn't see the changes I made in `k73ud`.

```
git diff k73ud..dj374 > master.patch
```

Answer (score 542, accepted):

Try

```
git diff k73ud^..dj374
```

to make sure to include all changes of `k73ud` in the resulting diff.

[`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) compares two endpoints ([instead of a commit range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)).
Since the OP wants to see the changes introduced by `k73ud`, they need to differentiate between the [first parent commit of `k73ud`: `k73ud^`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1956054/6309) (or [`k73ud^1` or `k73ud~`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222920/6309)).

That way, the `diff` results will include changes *since* `k73ud` parent (meaning including changes from `k73ud` itself), instead of changes introduced *since* `k73ud` (up to `dj374`).

Also you can try:

```
git diff oldCommit..newCommit
git diff k73ud..dj374
```

and (1 space, not more):

```
git diff oldCommit newCommit
git diff k73ud dj374
```

And if you need to get only files names (e.g. to copy hotfix them manually):

```
git diff k73ud dj374 --name-only
```

And you can get changes applied to another branch:

```
git diff k73ud dj374 > my.patch
git apply my.patch
```

Comment: Are you sure?  
git diff 275e8922ab4e995f47a753b88b75c3027444a54c..a8d9d944c32e945cbb9f60b3f724ecc580da86ae works, but git diff 275e8922ab4e995f47a753b88b75c3027444a54c^..a8d9d944c32e945cbb9f60b3f724ecc580da86ae get error message - "unknown revision or path not in the working tree"

Comment: @demas: works on my machine ;) you can also use `git diff 275e8^  a8d9d9` since it is the same then '`..`'.

Comment: @VonC In my machine, there is no need to use ^

Comment: @xi.lin what OS are you using? On Windows shell (cmd), you would need `^^`

Comment: @VonC Ubuntu 14.04. Only `git diff k73ud..dj374` is OK

Comment: @xi.lin I agree. I guess the branch topology must have been a special case for the OP to have to use `k73ud^`.

Comment: @Eug Are you sure about your edit `git diff dj374 k73ud`? `k73ud` is supposed to be the old commit, not the new one.

Comment: @Eug Thank you for your edit. Note that it does exclude changes from `k73ud` (the old commit) itself, which might not be what the OP wanted

Comment: @demas Is 275e892 the first commit in your repo? If so, it has no parent, so you wouldn't use `^` after it or `^^` on Windows Command Prompt (and using the caret would give that error). Doing so in that case would be the equivalent of `diff -r /dev/null /path/to/repo` (which is just every line with a `+` before it, or in other words, is nonsensical).

Comment: If your repository is on Github and you want to see the diff in a GUI then see this guide https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits#comparing-commits

Comment: @BradyDowling Agreed. And if you want to see a PR diff, you can do so in command line with the new `gh` CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031065/6309

Comment: Re: "[_it does exclude changes from k73ud (the old commit)_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368590/show-diff-between-commits#comment95336946_3368758)", I think the odd thing here is that the OP has the **newest commit** from his chronological list of changes **first in his `git diff` call**. That's fine; `git diff` just compares commit states & doesn't care about age, but it _is_ making this answer harder for me to wrap my head around. That is, I think the answer is still a step away from translating `git diff oldCommit newCommit` to "when & how `^` helps you diff _any_ two commits". 2¢

Answer (score 181):

To see the difference between:

Your working copy and staging area:

```
% git diff
```

Staging area and the latest commit:

```
% git diff --staged
```

Your working copy and commit 4ac0a6733:

```
% git diff 4ac0a6733
```

Commit 4ac0a6733 and the latest commit:

```
% git diff 4ac0a6733 HEAD
```

Commit 4ac0a6733 and commit 826793951

```
% git diff 4ac0a6733 826793951
```

For more explanation see [the official documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: also, if you really just want to see one file's diffs in those commits, `git diff {x} {y} -- filename` where `{x}` and `{y}` are any of those examples given. See also, `git log -p`, since there's some overlap.

Answer (score 72):

If you want to see the changes introduced with each commit, try "git log -p"

Comment: MVP! Now how can I do that between two specific hashes? And reversed (from older to more recent)? `git log -p --reverse old_hash..new_hash`!

Answer (score 16):

1. `gitk --all`
2. Select the first commit
3. *Right click* on the other, then **diff selected → this**

Comment: I am starting to trust gitk a little less because it is showing a different commiter Author than the actual one.

Answer (score 12):

I use `gitk` to see the difference:

```
gitk k73ud..dj374
```

It has a GUI mode so that reviewing is easier.

Answer (score 12):

To see the difference between two different commits (let's call them `a` and `b`), use

```
git diff a..b
```

- Note that the difference between `a` and `b` is opposite from `b` and `a`.

To see the difference between your last commit and not yet committed changes, use

```
git diff
```

If you want to be able to come back to the difference later, you can save it in a file.

```
git diff a..b > ../project.diff
```

Answer (score 11):

Simplest for checking the changes in the last 2 commits after pull:

```
git diff HEAD~2
```

Comment: for me this do a  diff between the last commit to penultimate (after pull) :
`git diff HEAD~1` .

Answer (score 9):

```
 1. git diff <commit-id> <commit-id>
 2. git diff HEAD^ HEAD     -(HEAD = current branch’s tip),( HEAD^ = version before the last commit)
 3. git diff HEAD^ HEAD — ./file     (comparison to specified file)
 4. git diff HEAD~5 HEAD           - (HEAD~5 refers to the last 5 commits.)
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a script which displays diff between two commits, works well on Ubuntu.

https://gist.github.com/jacobabrahamb4/a60624d6274ece7a0bd2d141b53407bc

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, subprocess, os

TOOLS = ['bcompare', 'meld']

def execute(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command)

def getTool():
    for tool in TOOLS:
        try:
            out = execute(['which', tool]).strip()
            if tool in out:
                return tool
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            pass
    return None

def printUsageAndExit():
    print 'Usage: python bdiff.py <project> <commit_one> <commit_two>'
    print 'Example: python bdiff.py <project> 0 1'
    print 'Example: python bdiff.py <project> fhejk7fe d78ewg9we'
    print 'Example: python bdiff.py <project> 0 d78ewg9we'
    sys.exit(0)

def getCommitIds(name, first, second):
    commit1 = None
    commit2 = None
    try:
        first_index = int(first) - 1
        second_index = int(second) - 1
        if int(first) < 0 or int(second) < 0:
            print "Cannot handle negative values: "
            sys.exit(0)
        logs = execute(['git', '-C', name, 'log', '--oneline', '--reverse']).splitlines()
        if first_index >= 0:
            commit1 = logs[first_index].split(' ')[0]
        if second_index >= 0:
            commit2 = logs[second_index].split(' ')[0]
    except ValueError:
        if first is not '0':
            commit1 = first
        if second is not '0':
            commit2 = second
    return commit1, commit2

def validateCommitIds(name, commit1, commit2):
    if not commit1 and not commit2:
        print "Nothing to do, exit!"
        return False
    try:
        if commit1:
            execute(['git', '-C', name, 'cat-file', '-t', commit1])
        if commit2:
            execute(['git', '-C', name, 'cat-file', '-t', commit2])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False
    return True

def cleanup(commit1, commit2):
        execute(['rm', '-rf', '/tmp/'+(commit1 if commit1 else '0'), '/tmp/'+(commit2 if commit2 else '0')])

def checkoutCommit(name, commit):
    if commit:
        execute(['git', 'clone', name, '/tmp/'+commit])
        execute(['git', '-C', '/tmp/'+commit, 'checkout', commit])
    else:
        execute(['mkdir', '/tmp/0'])

def compare(tool, commit1, commit2):
        execute([tool, '/tmp/'+(commit1 if commit1 else '0'), '/tmp/'+(commit2 if commit2 else '0')])

if __name__=='__main__':
    tool = getTool()
    if not tool:
        print "No GUI diff tools, install bcompare or meld"
        sys.exit(0)
    if len(sys.argv) is not 4:
        printUsageAndExit()

    name, first, second = None, 0, 0
    try:
        name, first, second = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]
    except IndexError:
        printUsageAndExit()

    commit1, commit2 = getCommitIds(name, first, second)

    if validateCommitIds(name, commit1, commit2) is False:
        sys.exit(0)

    cleanup(commit1, commit2)

    try:
        checkoutCommit(name, commit1)
        checkoutCommit(name, commit2)
        compare(tool, commit1, commit2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        cleanup(commit1, commit2)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I always love using the command line and have user friendly tools (with GUI) at my hand. Best of both worlds. Here is how I do it to compare two commits in Git.

You can show the diff between two commits like the following.

Edit your git config file in a TEXT EDITOR:

```
git config --global -e
```

Set up a proper diff tool (user friendly) like Meld like this in Windows in the Git config file:

```
[difftool "meld"]
cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe" "LOCAL\" \"REMOTE" --label "DIFF (ORIGINAL MY)"
prompt = false
path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe
```

Meld can be installed using Chocolatey like this from the COMMAND LINE:

```
choco install meld
```

Let's define a shell function to help us compare two sha-s (commits) under [alias] in the TEXT EDITOR:

```
[alias]
showchangesbetween = "!w() { git difftool \"$1\" \"$2\" --dir-diff --ignore-all-space; }; w"
```

To compare the commits with the help of Meld (or your other favorite diff tool, just type at the COMMAND LINE:

```
git showchangesbetween somesha123 somesha456
```

The commit sha-s are easily visible typing

```
 git log
```

for example.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer is good.

Just putting it again here, so its easy to understand & try in future

```
git diff c1...c2 > mypatch_1.patch  
git diff c1..c2  > mypatch_2.patch  
git diff c1^..c2 > mypatch_3.patch
```

I got the same diff for all the above commands.

Above helps in
1. seeing difference of between commit c1 & another commit c2
2. also making a patch file that shows diff and can be used to apply changes to another branch

If it not showing difference correctly
then c1 & c2 may be taken wrong
so adjust them to a before commit like c1 to c0, or to one after like c2 to c3

Use `gitk` to see the commits SHAs, 1st 8 characters are enough to use them as c0, c1, c2 or c3. You can also see the commits ids from Gitlab > Repository > Commits, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Command below perfectly works for me on Ubuntu 20.04 and git v2.25.1:

```sh
git diff <base-commit-id> <target-commit-id>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the last two commits

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
```

by extension to compare 2 commits,that can be for example

```
git diff HEAD~6 HEAD~3
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have one more commit at the bottom (oldest), then this becomes pretty easy:

```
commit dj374
made changes

commit y4746
made changes

commit k73ud
made changes

commit oldestCommit
made changes
```

Now, using below will easily server the purpose.

```
git diff k73ud oldestCommit
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this command for the difference between commit and unstaged:

```
git difftool --dir-diff
```