# How to diff committed changes in difftool?

Tags: git

My diff tool works for my local change such as `git difftool -x mytool.exe`, how could I use the same diff tool for committed change? I tried `git show`, `git log`, but cannot find such option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [show diff between commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368590/show-diff-between-commits)

Comment: You need to specify the sha:s the commits you would like to diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use this command to see graphical diff introduced by most recent commit:

```
 git difftool HEAD~
```

(this assumes that no local changes are made. if they are, you will see local changes in this diff added up).

You can also specify any specific commit or branch instead, something like

```
 git difftool abc123~..abc123
```