# How do we diff in Git?

Tags: git, clearcase

When I have a file, e.g. `x.java` in Git, how can I see the differences from previous versions in Git?

In [ClearCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase) we do a diff graphically or from the CLI? How do we do this in Git in CLI mode?

Comment: Are you asking about [`git diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)?

Comment: Git also supports a graphical mode, try `git gui` - this brings up a UI which allows to browse the whole version history, including diffs to previous versions (open "Repository/Visualize all Branch history")

Comment: @Andreas:just type `git gui` in cli?

Comment: @Jim: Yes, just `git gui`, see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html. Through the context menu of any entry in the history browser, you can also diff to any other commit, not only to the previous one. There are also some other graphical git frontends, see http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show diff between commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368590/show-diff-between-commits)

Answer (score 2):

`git diff HEAD~1 x.java`

This will compare your file with the same file one commit back

The most recent change of file would be

`git log -n 1 -- x.java`, then you can copy commit hash a use it in `git diff`.

You can also run GUI with `gitk x.java`

Comment: What if I want to compare with a file 10 versions back? Is it same command with `HEAD~10`?

Comment: Of course, that file might not have changed in the last commit (or the last 10 commits).

Comment: Yes, I thought this is obvious

Comment: in clearcase, you could compare to previous version irrelevant of how long in the history the previous version was. I think OP is looking for something equal to that.

Comment: @eis: Then the command is simply `git diff` without specifying version number.\

Answer (score 1):

If you know the commit numbers and you want to compare this file between commits, you can do this command:

```
git diff <commit_old> <commit_new> x.java
```

Or you can also install and use any external tool for comparing:

```
git difftool x.java
```

For using `difftool`, you should have installed and configured difftool on your local system.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to inspect when and how a particular file changed is with:

```
git log -p x.java
```

This will show you the commits that changed `file.java` (ignoring the commits that don't) with diffs describing the changes to the file. After locating commit(s) of interest, you can produce diffs using:

```
git diff COMMIT_ID x.java               # diff between COMMIT_ID and HEAD
git diff COMMIT_ID1 COMMIT_ID2 x.java   # diff between COMMIT_ID1 and COMMIT_ID2
```