# How do you recreate the GitHub pull request diff on the commandline?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

While working on a branch that I've opened a pull request on, I would like to see the exact same diff that GitHub displays on the commandline. What is the particular git diff command that replicates the list of changes GitHub displays for a pull request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make git diff show the same result as github's pull request diff?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763836/how-to-make-git-diff-show-the-same-result-as-githubs-pull-request-diff)

Comment: This question is 2 years older than the one you linked to. So the other is the duplicate ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to do any git fetch and update a local PR branch, you simply can use **[cli/cli](https://github.com/cli/cli)**, the command-line interface for GitHub.

The [release 0.9.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v0.9.0) includes **[`gh pr diff`](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/962)**

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/98482/82266353-13a03300-992f-11ea-8d71-2a0995707f87.png]

Comment: It took 6 years, but finally there is a completely satisfying answer.

Answer (score 9):

The closest thing is to diff with the common ancestor between your feature-branch and your base-branch.

Something like:

```
git diff `git merge-base feature-branch base-branch`
```

Comment: pic: my bad didn't RTFM & the command suggested it could do a merge

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a way to get the actual diff format closer to Github style but `$ git diff master...<branch_name>` seems to show the set of changes that a pull request would show (assuming it's a pull request against `master`). The list of changed files in a pull request seems to be equivalent to `$ git diff --name-status master...<branch_name>`. I guess this all assumes that your local branches are up-to-date with the remote Github branches

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to check against the base branch called `master`:

```
git diff $(git merge-base --fork-point master)
```

This will give all the changes since the branch was made, including yet uncommitted changes!

This command gives the same results as the one in @pic's answer, but it's a bit simpler as it doesn't require knowing the feature-branch.

If you want only the committed changes, similar to `gh pr diff` command as in @VonC's answer, the following command will give the same results:

```
git diff $(git merge-base --fork-point master) HEAD
```

The `git diff` way approach could be more useful in some situations, since you have all the other `git diff` features available. For example, if you don't want the diff, but instead want to know which files were modified, you can just pass the `--name-only`:

```
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base --fork-point master)
```

which you can't do with `gh`.

Comment: These commands don't give me the same output as `gh pr diff`. They give me every file that's changed between the feature branch and the master branch, i.e. if there have been other merges to `master` since the fork was created, they'll be listed as well

Comment: Right, I found issues with this too since I first wrote it. Try:

`git diff $(git merge-base master HEAD)` instead.

I should probably update this answer. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Reviewing and Synchronising](https://training.github.com/kit/advanced/#reviewing-synchronizing) section in GitHub advanced training. In particular, after fetching the pull request you can view the diff prior to merging:

```
$ git fetch origin refs/pull/1/head
$ git show FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without pulling down the refs? This seems like workflow/annoyance. I would prefer to use a set of commands completely using the git commandline without fetching the extra refs created by GitHub. Like `git diff ...master + flags`.

Answer (score -1):

`git diff branchA branchB` should work, no?

More info on other perhaps useful [diff notations can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif)