# Getting the diff with name, status, and commit sha

Tags: git, diff, commit, sha

I want to get the list of modified files in a pull request and group them by their commits sha.
I have only found the **git diff --name-status** but it doesn't return the commit sha:

I have a backup plan to use **git format-patch -1** , but the results are large files that includes the content of the files, which makes it very inefficient to parse.

I was wondering if there is another way to approach this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make git diff show the same result as github's pull request diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763836/how-to-make-git-diff-show-the-same-result-as-githubs-pull-request-diff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I needed:

**git show --diff-filter=dr --name-only sha**

--diff-filter=dr because I wanted to filter out deleted or renamed files.

Btw, I was asking this because the GitHub API has limitations on the number of files it returns for a commit. So, I needed to clone the repo and do it locally.

@phd:
Thanks for your help, it guided me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To list files modified in commits run

```
git log --name-only
```

You can modify the output using huge number of [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) options.

But that has nothing to do with backup so you perhaps need to change your backup plans.