# Git log - find last use of function

Tags: git

Is there an easy way to find out at what commit a certain function stopped being used? There have been too many times I find a function that I thought I was using, but nothing seems to be calling it, which leaves me wondering when and why I did this.

Comment: This is a job for [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) helped by `grep` or a similar tool.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368590/show-diff-between-commits

Comment: @axiac thank you, I will check it out.

Comment: @JossieCalderon I was hoping to find a less manual way

Comment: Do you know what file or folder the function was called in?

Comment: @axiac or `git log -S` or `git log -G`, which might be simpler for `git`-non-gurus...

Comment: @twalberg I didn't know about `-S` or `-G` options of `git log`. Learned something today. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### git log -S

From `git log --help`:

> -S<string>
>
> Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for the scripter’s use.
>
> It is useful when you’re looking for an exact block of code (like a struct), and want to know the history of that block since it first came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed the interesting block in the preimage back into
>              -S, and keep going until you get the very first version of the block.

### git log --patch | git log -p

This shows the diff patch for each commit. The `+` at the start of lines, highlighted green, are lines that were added. The `-` at the start of lines, highlighted red, are lines that were removed.

### Example: Combined Together:

Let's say I want to know the last time I used the python function `subprocess.call()`. We can search for the string `subprocess\.call\(` as the argument for the -S diff option like so:

```
git log -Ssubprocess\.call\( --patch
```

This use of git log will show the log for each commit that has the text change that you specified, and show the diff patches for each of those commits.

#### Bonus:

If I want to know how I used a function that no longer has anything calling it, I would simply:

```
text=subprocess\.call\(
git log --patch -S$text | grep -m 10 "$text"
```

or if I want to know the last time it was specifically removed:

```
text=subprocess\.call\(
git log --patch -S$text | grep -m 1 "^-.*$text"
```

Comment: Adding a file path at the end of the git log commands further narrow down file(s) to search through.