# Getting all changes from one Git commit to another

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a partially working command I am using to get all the changed/new files between two Git commits, that being:

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT $head_commit_id $older_commit_id | xargs tar -cf project.tar -T -
```

This has been working fine, but I recently did some filename changes where only the *case* was changed of the starting letter - I thought this would be covered by the `R` flag in the `filter` definition; but when I exported the files I got all the files, but they still had their previous filenames.

Am I doing something wrong here!?

**Edit:** I just noticed I am also not getting *new* files either; so that's possibly also related to the changed filenames too?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368590/show-diff-between-commits  ?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Yes, I believe if I remove the ` | xargs tar -cf project.tar -T - ` part at the end then I just get a diff output.

Comment: By default `git diff-tree` *does not* do rename detection, so you will never get any `R` files. But if you are working on a case-folding file system, file name `Foo` and file name `foo` are the same name anyway, so you get nothing at all.  Note: If you are asking for a diff from newer to older, you get instructions on how to *un*-do things. An added file (from older to newer) will give you a *delete* instruction (to change newer to older), and your filter excludes `D`.

Comment: Did you try option --find-renames[=<n>]  ?

Comment: I have posted a new question as this one was getting a little out of order and I needed to explain things better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458005/need-to-get-all-file-differences-added-modified-renamed-between-two-git-comi