# Creating new local git repository from different versions of a java project files

Tags: java, git

I am new to git, I have many versions of a project stored in my local computer I wish to do the following

1. create a local repository in git from these versions with differently named root directory
2. see the differences between the versions

pl. help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new directory, henceforth `x`, and `cd x`. Then run `git init`. This will start a new empty git repository inside the `x` directory. A git repository is a folder that has a `.git` subdirectory.

Copy the files from the first version of your project, paste them inside `x`.

Create a `.gitignore` file inside `x` and tell it which files of the project you do not wish be tracked by git. See [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-gitignore-file) for more info.

After you're done, run `git add -A` to tell git to track all the files in the directory and prepare them for committing (this will add all files except for the ones mentioned in `.gitignore`).

Now run `git commit -m "This is the first version of my project"`

Now for the second version - completely overwrite all the files inside `x` with the files of the second version (by deleting everything except for `.gitignore` and `.git` and pasting the files of the second version). Then performs the commands similar to before:

`git add -A`

`git commit -m "Second version of my project"`.

Repeat these steps for all versions - overwrite files, git add, git commit, repeat.

You now have a local git repository, with each commit corresponding to a version of your Java project.

You can see the differences between the versions using the `git diff` [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684991/791430) or a [Git GUI tool of your choice](https://github.com/dictcp/awesome-git#client) tool which allow you to explore your newly created repository.

You can now also upload your repository to a Git hosting service of your choice (popular ones being [Github](https://github.com/), [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org), [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) and more) by creating an empty repository inside those services and adding it as a [remote](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/glossary/remote) in your local repository and pushing the master branch (thus syncing the local copy of the repository with the remote host).

Note that this could be automated if you have a lot of versions, but such automation would largely depend on how your current "folder versioning" is structured, so this is up to you.