# In git, referring a commit - what means the expressions M"`

Tags: git

Im' looginkg [this guide](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

And I see they use M^ and M" with grave accecnt (sorry, i don't know how to put it), I could imagine that M^ is a reference to the inmediatly parent, but I don't know what mean M"+grave_accent.

Comment: This is similar to Markdown syntax. The backticks aren't actually part of the command.

Comment: @JanWilamowski I think it is github flavoured markdown syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual expression is:

```
  `"diff M^..M"`
```

The `` (backticks) are not important (code fence) and the `"` is not part of the diff command.

The true expression is:

```
 git diff M^..M
```

Meaning "compare the parent of M with M, as explained in "[Show diff between commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368758/6309)".

Comment: what a mistake from my side, thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: @user13182570 No problem. It is still a good question, which will help others.