# Get full history of changes

Tags: git, git-log

For some legal reasons I need to show all of the contributions that I've made to a projet.

Is there a way, using only the local git to see all of the diff of all files in between each commits? Or other informations like the total number of changes or lines of code.

At the moment I only have a list of commits with git logs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show diff between commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368590/show-diff-between-commits)

Comment: Hi @joshmeranda, only partly as I need to show a diff between all of the commits

Comment: What does "between all of the commits" mean, exactly? Are you looking to export a long list of diffs, one for every commit made to the project?

Comment: The answer I linked shows you how to get the diff between commits. If you need to show the diffs of a commit, iterate over your list of commits and take the diff between the taget commits parent and the targe tcommit: `git diff <parent> <commit>`. If you need more specificity for each of those parts you probably need to open new questions for each part

Comment: @IMSoP exactly what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see all commits created by you and what change they contain compared to their parent commit, you can simply filter the by author name and have it show the commit patches:

```
git log --author=youremail --patch --all
```