# Invalid Upstream Error while Modifying a Specified Git Commit (Not HEAD)

Tags: git

I am trying to learn how to modify a specified commit (fe4e3fc) that is not HEAD by following [@ZelluX answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit) . However, I encountered the following error

```
$ git log --oneline
b18762f Added Hey Hey
aa9c57d Put Hey in test
fe4e3fc Initial Test
$ git rebase --interactive fe4e3fc^
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream fe4e3fc^
$
```

I noticed that he had the `^` after the hash in his answer. Any assistance helping me understand how to edit a commit that is not HEAD will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What answer are you referring to? I don't see a link to another SO question.

Comment: The link is after @ZelluX. I'll make the link wider now

Comment: I see now - I've visited it before so it didn't stand out at all. My mistake.

Comment: +1 No, my bad, I should have made the link much wider to begin with. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Potentially handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-amend-modify-change-the-first-root-initial-commit-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` character means "find the first parent of the commit with this ref/hash". Therefore, `fe4e3fc^` means "find the parent of the commit with hash `fe4e3fc`". Since that is the initial commit for the repo, this is naturally impossible, because there are no commits prior to that one.

Also worth knowing about is the `~` character, which is similarly used to specify the parent (or grandparent, etc.) of a commit. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955985/what-does-the-caret-character-mean-in-git) for some detail on how `^` and `~` work. In this case, you could use `HEAD~2` and be referring to the same commit, `fe4e3fc`, because it is two "generations" back from `HEAD`.

If your goal is to modify the initial commit in some way, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-amend-modify-change-the-first-root-initial-commit-in-git).

Comment: +1 Ohhh ok so I can leave out `^` for the initial commit. Thanks

Comment: @Anthony Please see my edit - the linked question should be just what you need.