# what does head name followed by the '^' character means

Tags: git

I've seen the following:

```
git cat-file -p master^
```

I'm curios as to what the `^` character following the branch name means? If I put it without this character like this:

```
git cat-file -p master
```

It points to the commit specified inside `master` reference.

Comment: The man page for nearly every command that accepts one or more commits as an argument refers you to the `gitrevisions` man page, which documents the trailing `^` character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the caret (^) character mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955985/what-does-the-caret-character-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an [ancestry reference](http://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References) and means *"the commit before the one that is pointed by `master`"*, i.e. its parent.

Comment: The ~ also does the same, but counts the number of generations of ancestors, rather than ^<n> which is the n-th step-parent for merges.