# How can I remove all files in my git repo and update/push from my local git repo?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Is it possible to remove all files in a repository and update it with only the files I have in my local machine? The reason is that, there are certain files that is not necessary in my github and so I want to remove those files. Instead of removing the files one by one, I wanted to see if its possible to just remove all files in my git repo and update/push with only the files in my local machine. Hope its clear. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I delete a file from git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-git-repo)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, if you do a `git rm <filename>` and commit & push those changes. The file will disappear from the repository for that changeset and future commits.

The file will still be available for the previous revisions.

Answer (score 75):

You could do it like this:

```
cd /tmp
git clone /your/local/rep  # make a temp copy
cd rep
git rm -r *                # delete everything
cp -r /your/local/rep/* .  # get only the files you want
git add *                  # add them again
git status                 # everything but those copied will be removed
git commit -a -m 'deleting stuff'
cd /your/local/rep
git pull /tmp/rep          # now everything else has been removed
```

There's probably a oneliner for that…

Comment: `git rm -r *` doesn't work reliably because the `*` is expanded by the shell, so you're passing a list of files and directories that match `*` in the CWD. This will fail to match files starting with a `.` among other issues. The intent is probably to pass the * to git, achieved by quoting the asterisk: `git rm -r '*'`.

Answer (score 48):

First, remove all files from your Git repository using: `git rm -r *`

After that you should commit: using `git commit -m "your comment"`

After that you push using: `git push` (that's update the origin repository)

To verify your status using: `git status`

After that you can copy all your local files in the local Git folder, and you add them to the Git repository using: `git add -A`

You commit (`git commit -m "your comment"` and you push (`git push`)

Comment: This deleted all my files unexpectadly, except for what was in git-ignore. Was just trying to remove everything from git repo not the file system.

Comment: `git rm -r *` doesn't work reliably because the `*` is expanded by the shell, so you're passing a list of files and directories that match `*` in the CWD. This will fail to match files starting with a `.` among other issues. The intent is probably to pass the * to git, achieved by quoting the asterisk: `git rm -r '*'`.

Answer (score 20):

Warning: this will delete your files, make sure you have a backup or can revert the commit.

Delete all elements in repository:

```
$ git rm -r *
```

then:

```
$ git commit -m 'Delete all the stuff'
```

Comment: `git rm -r *` doesn't work reliably because the `*` is expanded by the shell, so you're passing a list of files and directories that match `*` in the CWD. This will fail to match files starting with a `.` among other issues. The intent is probably to pass the * to git, achieved by quoting the asterisk: `git rm -r '*'`.

Answer (score 14):

In my case

`git rm -r .`

made the job

Answer (score 7):

First of all, Navigate to your Folder using **cd** ( change directory) command. Then make sure you are in the correct git branch which you want to work by using the command

```
git branch
```

If you want to delete the entire files. you can do the same by using

`git rm -r .`

for deleting a single file,

`git rm file1.txt` ( file1.txt - file Name )

for delete a folder,

`git rm -r foldername`

After deleting the files or folders, you should commit it:

```
git commit -m "your comment"
```

Then you can push the branch:

```
git push
// for example, 
git push origin develop
```

(it will update the origin repository)

Answer (score 6):

This process is simple, and follows the same flow as any git commit.

1. Make sure your repo is fully up to date. (ex: `git pull`)
2. Navigate to your repo folder on your local disk.
3. Delete the files you don't want anymore.
4. Then `git commit -m "nuke and start again"`
5. Then `git push`
6. Profit.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do :

```
git rm -r *
```

but at the end for me works :

```
git rm -r .
```

I hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 2):

Just running it, solved for me:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "remove gitignore files"
git push
```

as answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50675909/3294762

Answer (score 1):

Do a `git add -A` from the top of the working copy, take a look at `git status` and/or `git diff --cached` to review what you're about to do, then `git commit` the result.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all elements in repository:

```
 git rm -r * -f -q
```

then:

```
 git commit -m 'Delete all the stuff'
```

then:

```
 git push -u origin master
```

then:

```
 Username for : "Your Username" 
 Password for : "Your Password"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), you can simply navigate inside the parent directory of your local repository and delete all of the files inside the parent directory. Then, commit and push your changes. Your repository will be cleansed of all files.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like this

```
git rm --cached -r * -f
```

And it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files not belonging to a repositiory (e.g. for a clean-build after switching a branch):

```
 git status | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score -2):

Delete the hidden `.git` folder (that you can locate within your project folder) and again start the process of creating a git repository using `git init` command.

Comment: OP specifies remote not local.