# Remove node_modules from git in vscode

Tags: git, node-modules

Getting error while removing `node_modules` in git, vscode terminal

```
 git rm -r --cached node_modules
```

**Error:**

> fatal error: **pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any files**

Comment: I don't understand. If they're being ignored and not tracked, what's the issue?

Comment: not able to remove node_modules from git in vscode, but everything looks clear

Comment: You keep saying "remove from git in vscode". But it sounds like the files are not "in git"? Why not just delete the folder if you don't want them in vscode?

Comment: If we're confusing you, perhaps include a screenshot to the question?

Comment: I manually deleted the node_modules folder and updated npm packages through package.json, git comment not helped out.

Comment: What do you mean "git comment not helped out"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove file from Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history)

Answer (score 354):

1. make .gitignore file.
2. add node_modules/ line to gitignore file
3. run this command

   `git rm -r --cached .
   git add .
   git commit -m "remove gitignore files"
   git push`

Comment: Aha! The key is `git rm -r --cached .` that's what I was forgetting.

Comment: Don't forget the `.` in `git rm -r --cached .` if you don't write the dot it wont work. It could be hard to see.

Comment: If you're using VSCode, you may need to restart it to have it "visually" update (i.e. this answer worked perfectly, but VSCode may not immediately grey out the node_modules folder).

Answer (score 60):

I faced the same issue. Do the below steps -

- Make .gitignore file.
- Run below commands in your terminal

  `git rm -r --cached node_modules`

  `git commit -am "node_modules be gone!"`

  `git push origin master`

That's all!

You are good to go!

Comment: @TarunNagpal I assume you understand what commits and pushes are. The first command recursively (`-r`) removes (`rm`) the `--cached` `node_modules` directory. `rm -r` is a *nix command borrowed here by git.

Answer (score 23):

Make `.gitignore` file in your project directory.

`.gitignore` file will look like this

```
/Folder_name
```

Type in below commands in the terminal or equivalent:

```
git rm -r --cached Folder_name (remove the directory from git but not delete it from the filesystem/locally)

git commit -m "remove unused directory"

git push origin <your-git-branch> (can be master or develop or others)
```

Answer (score 15):

Create `.gitignore` file and add `node_modules` there:

```
touch .gitignore && echo "node_modules" >> .gitignore
```

Remove cached data:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Update your last commit:

```
git add .

git commit --amend --no-edit

git push --force-with-lease
```

Answer (score 7):

The error means `node_modules` directory is not under git version control. There are 2 possibilities:

- They are not added to `Git` yet. Try running `git status` command, to see whether they appear as `untracked` files.
- It has already been added into your `gitignore` file. To list all ignored files, try this command: `git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard`

Answer (score 7):

Note that the currently accepted answer does NOT delete it completely and it will remain in the history. If you want it to be **deleted completely** from your history, i.e., from all past commits in which this directory exists in, you can use either of these ways:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch node_modules" HEAD
```

(Read more about it here: [7.6 Git Tools - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History))

Or, you can use a third-party plugin called **[filter repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)** - which is indeed the officially recommended method by Git too:

```
git filter-repo --path node_modules --invert-paths
```

(Read more on how to use here: [Installation](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md#installation-via-pip) and [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#cheat-sheet-conversion-of-examples-from-the-filter-branch-manpage) and [Documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html))

In both cases however, **notice that you're re-writing the history** which might be a nightmare when working in a team... . So either use this in your own local branch/environment, or make sure you know no one has any better options and let all of your mates know about it beforehand.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks it helped.

Comment: one of the best solution I've ever seen

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a file `.gitignore`
2. Add `node_modules/*`  line to `gitignore` file
3. Run the below commands in Your terminal

   ```
   git rm -r --cached node_modules 

   git add .


   git commit -m "Remove node_modules from git in vscode"

   git push
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are great. They are just not things you remember all the time. So you have to check back online every time you need to do this.

Here is a quick way to remove node_modules with git commands you are already familiar with.

- First create a `.gitignore` file and add `/node_modules` to it.
- Then delete the `node_modules` folder and commit your changes.

Git will interpret this as a folder deletion and will remove the node_modules folder on `git push` from Github or whatever source control you use.

- Then run `npm i` or `yarn install` to recreate node_module from
  package.json automatically in your development environment.

Answer (score 3):

Once git starts tracking a file or a folder it won't stop even if you add it to .gitignore

You will need to delete it from the .git repository. I exclusively use a local one, typically located at the root of the project's source.

As of today 20200408, it does not appear there is a mouse click approach to remove the annoying file/folder from git.

You will have to use the terminal.

Press **Ctrl-J** then select **Terminal** tab

or from VSCode menu select **Terminal** / **New Terminal**

Then issue something like the following command

```
git  rm -r --cached  www/index.html
```

The following exclude

```
 www/
```

was already in my .gitignore file.

In your case you would want to add the "cancer folder" :)

```
node_modules/
```

PS: Simple things made unnecessarily hard, I wonder why?

Below is the zillion garbage of Git commands I never use.  Enjoy!

[image]

Answer (score -4):

You can remove folders from git (using the command-line or your IDE).
If you want to remove `node_modules` from git:

1. rename `node_modules` to `node_modulesx`
2. commit
3. rename `node_modulesx` back to `node_modules`
4. add `node_modules` to .gitignore (create the .gitignore file if needed)
5. commit

Now your `node_modules` folder still exists, but will not be committed to git anymore.