# Re-writing commit history ignoring a folder (in my case node_modules)

Tags: git

I just noticed that the project the junior developers in my company are working on have not added `node_modules` to `.gitignore` file at the beginning of the project... Now I was taking a look at the commit history and I noticed that the `git pull` took a lot of time and there were a lot of changes, so the reason was that they did not ignore `node_modules` directory .

All I want to do is re-write the commit history and `git push --force` and tell them to `git pull --rebase`.

Is there any way to re-write that history without that `node_modules` folder?

A Master in Git is needed here!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)

Comment: Why rewrite history? Just remove the folder from staging and commit now. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675829/remove-node-modules-from-git-in-vscode

Comment: Or a master of search engines.

Comment: @matt you're right, but let's say I'd like to compare several commits from the past, why should I see useless changes? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the history using `git filter-repo`.  This is one of its basic operations, so refer to the docs at https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html

(You also could do this with `git filter-branch`, but the `filter-branch` command itself recommends against using it any longer.)