# Git ignore node_modules

Tags: javascript, git

I have a file structure like this

master is:
~/Exercism/javascript

exercise files are:

```
~/Exercism/javascript/hello-world
~/Exercism/javascript/protein-translation
~/Exercism/javascript/resistor-color
...etc
```

EACH one of these folders has a node_modules folder that I want to ignore

My .gitignore file is located in:

```
~/Exercism/javascript
```

content of .gitignore:

```
**/node_modules/
```

git still won't ignore the node_modules folders. Is there something I need to run in git? Is my folder in the right place>

I have not committed anything yet but the repo is initiated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29820869/10116894

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820791/git-ignore-node-modules-folder-everywhere) helps

Comment: @c0m1t I have this exact setup, when I (git add .) it starts running through the node modules folders and the add process takes a very long time (I've never let it finish ctrl+c)

Comment: Are your node_modules already tracked? What is the output of `git status`? `git rm -r --cached node_modules` might help you.

Comment: @c0m1t git rm returns 'node_modules did not match any files'

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675829/remove-node-modules-from-git-in-vscode)

Comment: @c0m1t resolved, was still a .txt file

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify it as `node_modules/` in the .gitignore file and it will traverse through your parent folder as well as subfolders and ignore all directories called `node_modules` in each of your subfolders, as opposed to having to specify .gitignore files in each of your subdirectories.

Hope this helps you. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

Every folder should have a different `.gitignore` file, since all of those folders are different projects.
The fact that makes them different projects is that each of them have a different `node_modules` folder.

Change `.gitignore` content to

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
```

and put a copy in every folder.

Comment: I've done this and its still not working. Git add . starts running though a node_modules folder immediately and I ctrl+c out

Comment: ok, did you configured ignored files for your pc with `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global` ? have a look here before launching the command: https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/ignoring-files because it depends from what service (github, etc) you use

Comment: resolved, it was still a .txt file