# Changes occur in node_modules although it is in .gitignore file

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the following project directory structure
[image]

React_Native\reporTown file is used for the front-end. When I clone the code, I have to run "npm install" command in the reporTown folder to run the front-end. After executing npm install, I am executing npm start to run the project. However, when I execute the npm install command, there are a lot of (4k+) changes occur as can be seen from the image below:

In the upper directory's .gitignore file, I have

```
node_modules
**/node_modules
node_modules/
```

lines. In the reporTown .gitignore file which is in the reporTown folder, I have

```
/node_modules
node_modules/
node_modules
**/node_modules
```

lines.

It seems that I am not able to add the node_modules to the .gitignore file properly. What should I do so that I won't see the changes after I run the npm install command?
[image]

Comment: Does the repository already have the node_modules folder? If so, git will not ignore it. You need to manually tell git to remove it from source control by following the steps provided in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675829/remove-node-modules-from-git-in-vscode

Comment: Yes the project I am cloning from the github already has the node_modules folder. Should my team member delete the node_modules folder from the project and push to github?

Comment: Yes, he needs to follow the steps provided in the link, then push to Github the commit generated by it.

Comment: This has solved my issue, thank you