# Node js App not working on heroku some month after testing

Tags: node.js, express, github, heroku, hosting

I have read up solution from different stack overflow  but non solves the problem
This end point works fine on local host and heroku some month ago but now it works fine only on local host I get this error after I try to access the end point[image]

**server.js file**

```
'use strict';

  require("dotenv").config();
  require('./MongoDB/DB')

  const http = require('http');
 const express = require('express');
 const cors = require("cors");
 const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
  let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const port=process.env.PORT||5000;
const passportContol=require("./Passport/index")


app.use(cors())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1kb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true,limit: "1kb"}));
app.use(
mongoSanitize({
   replaceWith: '_',
  }),
);
app.use(passportContol.initialize());

app.set('trust proxy', 1);


 const router1=require('./Router/Account')
 const router2=require('./Router/Post')
 const router3=require('./Router/Request')

  app.use("/",router1);
  app.use("/",router2);
  app.use("/",router3);

   server.listen(port ,()=>console.log(`server started.... ${port}`))
```

**package.json**

```
      {
       "name": "api-campus-bet",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "description": "campus-bet api for soccer betting",
       "main": "server.js",
       "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node server.js",
        "dev": "nodemon server"
             },
          "author": "Ogbonna Chinaza",
         "license": "ISC",
           "dependencies": {
          "axios": "^0.26.1",
         "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
         "cookie": "^0.4.2",
         "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
          "cors": "^2.8.5",
           "csurf": "^1.11.0",
           "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
           "express": "^4.17.3",
          "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.2.0",
           "express-rate-limit": "^6.3.0",
             "ioredis": "^5.0.3",
         "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
          "mongoose": "^6.2.9",
        "passport": "^0.5.2",
      "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
      },
       "engines": {
      "node": "16.13.1"
     }
      }
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node server.js
```

WHAT I HAVE DONE

1. I have reinstall the  nodemodule i did this including package-lock.json
2. I have cleared heroku cache
   (git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
   $ git push heroku master)
3. I deleted the whole project on heroku and push a new one with no error message

with some other things

please I need help what have I done wrong

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by git it was including some files which should not be included when hosting like node module and the gitignore file. I solved the problem by using the solution in this site to remove those files.
[Remove node_modules from git in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675829/remove-node-modules-from-git-in-vscode)