# Cannot push code to GitHub, node modules too large

Tags: reactjs, github, node-modules

I have a react project with a root directory and a client directory. Earlier I had worked from just the root directory as usual but I decided to create a new client directory for the front-end code I'd been writing while I kept the back-end code in the root directory. After making this separation, I have not been able to push my code to GitHub. I get an error stating that the node_modules in the client folder contains files that are too large. I have tried to create a new repository and push there instead but it is still the same result, so the problem seems to come from my codebase. I have added node_modules to the gitignore folder in the root directory so that it does not get pushed to the repository but still to no avail. I have even tried git LFS for large file storage but I still get the same errors. I have already finished my project for the most part and I have been pushing code to my repository ever since. This problem just came out of nowhere. This is the message I get in my terminal

It gets to this point and halts here for a long time:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
Enumerating objects: 44178, done.
Counting objects: 100% (44178/44178), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31530/31530), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44175/44175), 386.79 MiB | 15.49 MiB/s, done.
Total 44175 (delta 11605), reused 43933 (delta 11488), pack-reused 0
```

Then eventually, this is the full message:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
Enumerating objects: 44178, done.
Counting objects: 100% (44178/44178), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31530/31530), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44175/44175), 386.79 MiB | 15.49 MiB/s, done.
Total 44175 (delta 11605), reused 43933 (delta 11488), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (11605/11605), completed with 1 local object.
remote: error: Trace: 404752adfd4ea24fa4470b58cfe8deab2314f93248e63256a319fb89bcdc4128
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/1.pack is 133.46 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/10.pack is 409.51 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/13.pack is 415.16 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/24.pack is 132.23 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/27.pack is 406.89 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/ojieprincewill/baroque.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ojieprincewill/baroque.git'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove node\_modules from git in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675829/remove-node-modules-from-git-in-vscode)

Comment: `node_modules` should not be in Git in the first place.

Comment: I have tried removing it from git by adding it to the gitignore file but it still does not work.

Comment: You will need to remove it from any commit you've already made before trying to push them, too.

Comment: After trying all solutions I found online and it still did not work, I decided to do a separation of concerns for both front end and backend code, pushing to respective repositories, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create .gitignore file in the root folder of your app.
2. Insert this line: **/node_modules**.
3. Commit your changes and push them to git.

**If you already made a commit before creating the .gitignore file, you should close your terminal and commit them again.*

**EDIT**

**package.json** file contains all of your dependencies. When you need to download your project on another device, all you need to do is run **npm install** - that will generate node_modules automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`/node_modules` folder should not be in the Git. To exclude this folder from being tracked by Git, you need to create a `.gitignore` file in the root directory of your project and add the following line in that file:

```
/node_modules
```

Then commit your changes again and push to your repository.