# how to remove a file from github and stop being tracked?

Tags: git, github

Though I had added my database.yml into .gitignore, it is still being added at github. Now

1. How should I remove it from github ? (I saw this [How to remove files from the GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11121352/692622), is this the only way to remove from github?)
2. How to stop it being added at github since it contains sensitive information

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're asking how to remove the file from the existing history on GitHub.

GitHub's help explains [exactly how to do that](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data):

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch database.yml' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's the way to remove files from Git repositories. Once you'll remove it and since you added this file into your `.gitignore` file it won't be tracked again. So if you want to keep this file locally, keep a copy somewhere else and then use the `git rm path/database.yaml` and then put it back.

Note that by adding more rules into the `.gitignore` file will not affect in any way the files that are already being tracked by git and it only affects the untracked files.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

- you will find plenty of .gitignore file examples in the [GitHub gitignore project](https://github.com/github/gitignore).
- `yml` files are not ignored enough (only [`Rails.ignore` has an `*.yml` included](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/225))
- if you are not careful, you can enable anyone to do a quick grep for sensitive file, with the project [**ghrabber**](https://github.com/cortesi/ghrabber), in your GitHub repo or any GitHub repo:

That means a simple command is enough to get all sensitive file for all repos:

```
./ghrabber.py "path:.bash_history"
```

> You get all bash command line history included by mistake in the git repo

```
./ghrabber.py "path:.htpasswd"
```

> You get all `htpasswd` files

```
./ghrabber.py "ext:mbox"
```

> You get mail boxes...

```
./ghrabber.py "path:databases.yml"
```

> you get connections logins/passwords to database...

(from [Korben.info - french](http://korben.info/ghrabber.html#WB1VXkWBuagXlmr2.99))