# How to delete single file in GitHub?

Tags: github

I accidentally added and committed a file from my local repo that I do not want added to my GitHub project's repo. Can I delete this file with terminal or can I manually delete it online?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github). Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/449070/464744).

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I delete a file from git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2047465/456814).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From command line you could do following:

```
git rm <file> - remove file locally and marks it for deletion
git commit -m"your message" - commit file to local repo
git push origin master - push the change to github.
```