# Git push not delete file from repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I am working on a Git repo in bitbucket

I deleted 2 files and did push command and.  I still see the files in the repo.

I always push to the master branch

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete a file from git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-git-repo)

Comment: Description of the problem is totally insuffiecient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add all the deleted changes using the command given below and then push it.

```
git add --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Git push -f {localbranch} {remotebranch}`