# Removing unwanted files from git/github

Tags: git, github

I earlier pushed many files to git, many of them where unwanted. I followed the following to remove those unwanted files (jar/lib/ide files etc).

[Remove Files - 1](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/)

[Remove Files  - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-git-repo/28772827#28772827)

Basically I did,

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch target'
```

I verified in github those files don't exist anymore. When I download my repo as zip in github its less than 1MB, however when I do a git clone, its still 100MB.

Upon further research I found after cloning,

`MyRepo/.git/objects/pack/pack-b6b2b82ecd58c551c3648b9ca97e4f8b29rrt3c2.pack` is **99.8 MB**. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you missed the last step of the [first link](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) (step 9):

```
git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

The `git gc` garbage collects.

I'd add that you should make sure you do not accidentally `git push` back the bloated content. I suggest removing local copies of all repositories and recloning once you are sure it works.

The second link you suggested almost entirely deals with removing the file from the repository *as a commit*; if you do this, you will still be able to check out a revision prior to the commit, so the contents of the file must obviously still be somewhere, hence your `git clone` does not reduce in size.

Comment: Tried all the steps again, doesn't work. I will probably find a manual work around, but I am curious how to get rid of it.

Comment: Is it possible that at some stage in the past the file had a different name? You might want to check `git filter-branch` was applying the filter to all branches.

Comment: I am seeing, WARNING 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged , WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged. I think its because I had earlier deleted the unnecessary files using `git rm -r --cached .idea`.

Comment: Try `git reset --hard [commit]` first.