# How to delete zip file from GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I uploaded a zip file to a repository in GitHub and I found out that every time I click on this zip file, it downloads the file (does not allow to explore the content of this zip file). However, I decided to delete this zip file from the repository. I pressed the delete button and it was successfully deleted but the problem is that I found the zip file in the `commits`. I tried to delete it from the `commit` but I couldn't. How can I delete it permanently from the `commits`?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use these commands on a Git Bash. And you must check all branches that this file appears and remove all last references:

-git rm file1.zip

-git commit -m "remove file1.zip"

You can check this link, "[How can I delete a file from git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-git-repo)". In the answers, there are any about GitHub plataform.