# Remove file from Version Control in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, gitignore

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.
I've put my project under Git, hosted it on GitHub.

When I first hit that <kbd>Share Project on GitHub</kbd> button, every single file was selected to be put under version control.

Now I want to exclude the module IML file from version control. Obliviously, I want to keep it on my hard disk. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to do this. How do I achieve this?

I tried to delete it from the web interface, but I'm getting some fatal errors while pulling/pushing.

Answer (score 77):

There is a little trick.

- Go to `File Menu-> Settings | Version Control | Confirmation`, then check the `Show options before adding to version control` setting under the `When files are created` section.
  Alternatively, you could check `Do not add`. It is mandatory that you do not check `Add silently`.
- Delete the file you don't want to be tracked by VCS.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> to undo the removal of the file.
  If IDE shows a popup window which lets you choose whether or not to add the new file to VCS, click `No`.
- Commit your local changes, and the files are removed from VCS.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed.  If i undeleted and then tried commit and push got an error.  Instead, delete, commit and push, then, with cursor on the package name, undelete but don't add to vc.  works great

Comment: IMPORTANT - step delete the files must be done in "Version Control Window" (Alt+9), tab local changes. If you delete files in project tree, there is no ctrl+z to get your files back.

Comment: These IDE developers... We need to thank them for the creativity they provoke in them hackers...

Answer (score 35):

Once you commit the file it will begin to be tracked.
In order to remove the file from this point you have to remove them from the repository.

What you need to do now is to delete the entire `.idea` folder, commit the deletion, add the `idea` extension to your `.gitignore` file.

---

Explaining how to do from command line, can be done via IDEA as well.

```
# Remove the file from the repository
git rm --cached .idea/

# now update your gitignore file to ignore this folder
echo '.idea' >> .gitignore

# add the .gitignore file
git add .gitignore

git commit -m "Removed .idea files"
git push origin <branch>
```

Comment: How do I access Git Bash from inside IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: `View - Tool Windows - Terminal` will open an embedded bash.

Comment: What you have to remember is this: remove the files and commit the remove and at the same time add it to the ignore file

Comment: Hi , what is the harmful of that if we have .idea in remote repository?

Comment: @miladsalimi the .idea directory contains values/settings working only on your local PC. So if you commit that, others who gets your .idea dir, could have problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362816/should-the-idea-folder-be-kept-under-source-control

Answer (score 2):

for subversion:

- go to file properties context menu > copy path
- open terminal use "svn rm --keep-local" to remove

  svn rm --keep-local /aa/bb/cc/myfile.txt

Comment: I do not get, why other answers get a +1 and this not. The question was, how to remove an already added file from Git version control, but keep the file locally. And this is the correct answer. I wonder just, why this property (--keep-local) is not selectable in IntelliJ (IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)) from under the Git menü / delete option.

Comment: @Kozaka because question is about `git` not `svn`. Dosen't mean anwser is incorrect, it just means it's not anwsering question at hand (note in question: "project under Git"). And Im sure it helped someone.