# Recover directory removed with git rm -rf

Tags: git

I added a directory to a local git repo using `git add` and then accidentally did `git rm -rf` (without committing before). Is there some way of recovering the files from this directory?

Comment: Wrote you a full answer below.

Comment: It seems that You need to use some data recovery software if You deleted whole dir (including .git dir) - try to not place new files on dusk (especially in this dir) until You try to recover data. 
http://superuser.com/questions/279733/undo-an-rm-rf-command

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can,

Read this: [How to undo changes in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716).

---

Once you add files to git they are started to be tracked and they are stored under the `.git` folder.

In they were just added and never commited they are refereed as `dangling objects`. Those object can be recovered.

---

#### Ho to restore dangling objects?

First we have to find them out

```
git fsck --full
```

[image]

Once you have the list of those object you need to view them and to find out which ones you need.

```
# Print out the content of the Object
git cat-file -p <SHA-1>

# If the object is a file you will simply see its content,
# Copy it and save it in a new file.
```

---

[image]

Comment: Glad to help, read the attached post about the HEAD, it will teach you new  things i assume.

Comment: Saved my day! who want a next step of recovering?

Comment: I owe you a beer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my recover.py utility, which will create a file for each hash:

```
enter code here


import subprocess
hashes=["01b6a7f272375bc99d98be0068c273b5bc4e9ff6",
"03620d7b53c8a48314c25a3ecdbe369553b01340","PUTYOUR HASHEZ HERE"]
for myhash in hashes:
    print "HASH", myhash
    bashCommand = "git cat-file -p "+ myhash
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    file = open("recover/"+myhash, "w")
    file.write(output)
    file.close()
```

This will write to recover folder all files you killed with git