# git remove file while mereging

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using bit bucket for version controlling.I have repository x,which contains two branches 1) master and 2) sub_branch.

I want to delete some file from master branch while merging sub_branch into master branch.

Though I have found the way to delete file : 
[How can I delete a file from git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-git-repo)

I have tried with following command:

```
git checkout master
git rm <my_file>
git commit -m 'delete file'
git merge sub_branch
```

unfortunately this dosen't work.

My question is I want to delete some file from a branch before I merge other branch with it.

Thanks a lot. please put your comments if you didn't get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the file, commit the change and merge the other branch.

```
git checkout master
git rm <my_file>
git commit -am 'delete file'
git merge sub_branch
```

Comment: @MaazPatel By "it didn't work" I suppose the merge ends with a conflict?

Comment: When I followed those steps , after merging, "git commit -am 'delete file'" this command has been not reflecting on server. and my file has been not removed from repository.

Comment: "didn't work"? means after  executing all the commands my file has been not removed from server nor that commit has been pushed. Do I need to push my master branch after merging so that it can reflect on server??

Comment: @MaazPatel You have deleted file locally. Of course you need to push your changes on the remote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **Add** (Stage deleted files) the changes before `Commit`.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rm <my_file>

$ git add -A  # staged deleted, modified & new files

$ git commit -m 'delete file'
$ git merge sub_branch
```

**Additional:** if conflict happens then Accept the `master` (*ours*) changes.

```
$ git checkout --ours -- .
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m 'Fix conflicts'
```