# Bitbucket reduce repo size with BFG

Tags: bitbucket, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

My team's repo on Bitbucket was 1.34GB due to some static assets (videos, images)

I've followed instructions from [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

and my repo is now 2.37GB which is over our 2GB quota and it is now read only.

The commands I've run were pretty much what's on the BFG Homepage,

1. git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
2. java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git
3. cd some-big-repo.git
4. git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
5. git push

After I run this commands my repo grew to the 2.37GB mark. However if I run `git count-objects -v` my size-pack is now: `size-pack: 1073518` as opposite as before it was `size-pack: 1213524`. So in theory my repo is smaller.

I dont know because this is hosted in Bitbucket cloud If I need them to run anything on the server or not, some places (gitlab, github) seem to need "them" to run `git gc` on the server.

Is this necessary? Is there anyway I can undo all my changes with that `git push`? I have the `some-big-repo.git.bfg-report` report with all the changes, but I dont know how to use that report to revert my changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [Bitbucket docs on *Garbage collecting dead data*](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html#Reducerepositorysize-MaintainingorcleaningupaGitrepository) say:

> After you push your changes, contact Support to run a git gc on the server for you. This is git garbage collection which runs housekeeping tasks on the repository to reflect the change in the size.

... have you asked them to run 'git gc' yet?

Comment: I did created a ticket. But I am still curious if there's an "official" way of undo changes caused by steps above, would be nice if this was a feature from BFG. Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

To address the second part of your question, you can use the backup you created to undo your changes. https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage