# How to remove a folder from remote repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a github repository which has a folder that i didnt mean to commit. I removed that folder from my local git repo, but when i push my local repo, all new changes are pushed, but the folder is still in my remote repository. how can i delete this folder from GITHUB?

Comment: How exactly did you remove that folder from your local repo? Did you commit the removal?

Comment: yes, i committed the removal. I just deleted the folder, then pushed to my remote repo. But it's still there on github

Comment: Delete and push is not enough. You must have committed: `git rm -rf folder && git commit && git push`

Comment: Now when the folder is already deleted you still need to commit deletion so try `git commit -a && git push`

Comment: Also for the future, you can try adding such folders in the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As commenters suggested, you can [delete the folder as part of a commit using `git rm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-a-git-repository).

Specifically,

```
git checkout <branch name>
git pull
git rm -rf <folder name>
git commit -m "<commit message>"
git push origin <branch name>
```