# git revert ended up giving error ! [remote rejected] error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:reponame/project

Tags: git, git-push, git-revert

I accidently pushed .idea/workspace.xml.
and made more push after that.

My code is merged on development branch.
My team member asked me to revert .idea/workspace.xml changes.

So I followed:

```
git revert <commit sha>

git push origin <my branch>
```

as commit reverted had some changes which i want to persist, therefore copied my changes from development and

```
git add .

git commit -m'added back changes in filepath'

git push origin mybranch
```

> ! [remote rejected]    mybranch -> mybranch  (pre-receive hook
> declined) error: failed to push some refs to
> 'git@bitbucket.org:reponame/projectname.git'

[image]

I tried to find solution on internet but could not figureout.
Any help would be appreciated.

I also tried git push with -force flag. but that also did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-a-git-repository

Comment: `mybranch` might be a protected branch and you don't have permission to update it without a merge/pull request.

Comment: @ElpieKay no, I have pushed changes on that branch earlier.

Comment: @Harsimer The new commit(s) may fail some tests in the hook, like bad commit message format or building failure.

Comment: @ElpieKay you were right ElpieKay, I have made last commit without adding JIRA ID which failed a hook.
Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: @Harsimer If so, I'd suggest your team update the hook to print more feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message in your text image says:

```
 ! [remote rejected]   mybranch -> mybranch  (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:reponame/projectname.git'
```

The first line contains the phrase `pre-receive hook declined`.  This means that something that is *not* part of Git itself is doing some checking on the commits you've asked the Git over at Bitbucket to accept.  That thing-that-did-the-checking does not like your commits, for some reason.

Ideally, any pre-receive hook that rejects commits should tell you *why* it is rejecting the commits.  If it did, you should include that in your question.  Any messages from such a hook would appear above the  `! [remote rejected]` line, prefixed with the word `remote:` for each line.

Per [your own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068590/git-revert-ended-up-giving-error-remote-rejected-error-failed-to-push-some#comment111531127_63068590):

> I have made last commit without adding JIRA ID which failed a hook

it was a pre-receive check to make sure that each commit contains a JIRA ID.

You will need to replace the bad commit(s) with new-and-improved commit(s) that meet the requirements of your pre-receive hook.