# How does one .gitignore pickle files in python?

Tags: python, gitignore

How does one add pickle files to their .gitignore file?

I have tried:

```
*.csv
*.pkl
```

The CSV is ignored but not the pickle file.

Note that the pickle file was originally added so maybe its downstream(?) and can no longer be removed?

Comment: `.gitignore` only effects new files, it will not delete existing files

Comment: Any safe way to delete the file on remote only?

Comment: `git rm --cached` will delete from git but not the local copy

Comment: @Cybernetic, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-a-git-repository#comment52108137_2047477

Comment: Thanks. Removed the pickle file from remote only. Still didn't get ignored on next push. Weird.

Comment: @Cybernetic, have you tried pushing everything as it is, then deleting from remote, then putting `*.pkl` in `.gitignore` and _then_ committing & pushing everything again?