# How do I remove file from git since git rm does not work?

Tags: git

I am trying to remove a file from the git repository. However, when I do:

```
git rm <file name>
fatal: pathspec 'file1.txt' did not match any files
```

[image: fatal: pathspec 'file1.txt' did not match any files]

The two files still untracked files!

Comment: remove the files (using simply rm) and commit the 'change' (=deletions) to the repo.

Comment: Untracked files aren't in the current commit and won't be in the next commit. *None* of the files that you can see right now are *in* the repository; the ones that are in the repository got copied out to make (some of) the ones you can see. The files you can see and work on/with are *your* files, not Git's; Git copies committed files *to* this area on checkout, but doesn't remove other files that you created yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete a file from a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: @torek I know that's shorter than your usual length of answer, but I think that does make a good answer here? It's basically all I'd answer with

Answer (score 0):

Here, `git rm` is telling you that the file you are telling it to remove is *already not going to be in the next commit you make:*

> ```
> $ git rm new.html
> fatal: pathspec 'new.html' did not match any files
> ```

You added this last line:

> The two files still untracked files!

I don't quite know what you mean to say here (among other things, this sentence has no verb), but the fact is that an *untracked file* is a file that *won't be in the next commit you make*.  It's therefore impossible for Git to remove it from the proposed next commit: it's not *in* the proposed next commit.

The `git rm` command will remove a file from two places: the proposed next commit, *and* your working tree.  For this to happen, the file has to be in both places.

Files that you can see—that show up in `ls` output—are not actually the files that are in the repository.  When you run `git checkout`, Git will copy files that *are* in the repository into your working tree, but other files that *already exist* in your working tree—that you put there yourself, for instance—just sit there, unmodified.  They're not in the proposed next commit, because the initial proposed next commit consists of the files copied out of the *current* commit.

When `git status` reports files as *untracked*, that means they are not in your proposed next commit, so that if you commit now, they will not be in that commit.