# Delete from github repository each file that has been deleted in local folder

Tags: git, commit

I'm new to git, and I can't find an answer for that which is kind of weird.
Here is my problem:
I want to commit changes to all files within my folder called "folder1"
here is the content of "folder1":

```
folder1
    pyproject1.py
    pyproject2.py
    myimg.png
```

To do that, I commit my changes to my github repository, using the following command lines:

```
git add *
git commit-m"my changes"
git push origin main
```

But if I try to remove for example the file "myimg.png" from my local folder, and execute again the following command lines:

```
git add *
git commit-m"my changes"
git push origin main
```

The file myimg.png isn't removed from the github repository. How can I make sure that every time I commit a change in my local folder, every file that is not anymore in my local folder gets deleted from the repository ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a file from a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-do-i-delete-a-file-from-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. My goal was to automatically add all removed files so that they don't appear anymore on my repository. The problem with doing something like `git rm myimg.png` is that I don't want to have to do it for each and every file that I have deleted in my folder. The solution is to use `git add .` instead of `git add *`. And if I want to add modified and removed files that are in my current folder, I should use `git add -A .`. More informations can be found on this website for example: https://intellipaat.com/community/14450/git-add-all-files-modified-deleted-and-untracked

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it *is* possible to remove a file with `git add`.  This is a bit weird—well, it seems that way to *me* at least—since "add" seems to mean, well, *add*, not *remove*.  But there's a much more direct command that literally means *remove*, which is `git rm`.

So, what you want is:

```
git rm myimg.png
```

which will remove the file from both your working tree and Git's *index* aka *staging area* (more about this in a moment), and then:

```
git add
```

any other updated files as usual, and then:

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

(you can write the quotes the way you did; this is just my own preference as `-m` takes one argument, which in the old 1980s-days usually had to be separate like this, even though Git itself didn't come into existence until the early 2000s).

## Long and optional reading: what's really going on here

Whatever Git tutorial you've been using has done you a bit of a disservice here by not teaching you first about Git's oddities.  Git is a *distributed* version control system (DVCS), which means extra oddities, but this contains the phrase "version control system", which itself has some basic ideas: any [Version Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) System in general needs to offer you a way to "get back" old versions.  There are a lot of different ways to achieve this.  Git, being one of the more modern VCSes (along with Mercurial and Subversion and Bazaar and many others), is based on the idea of *commits*.  The commits act as the checkpoints: you can go back to any older commit, any time you like.

In order to make this work, Git stores every *commit* as a frozen-for-all-time *full snapshot* of *every file* (plus a bit more, that we won't cover here at all).  To keep this from using up all your disk space instantly, Git uses a lot of clever tricks, including the idea of *de-duplicating content*.  So if you make 100 commits, each of which contains a 100 megabyte file but the file itself is the *same* in all 100 commits, rather than making 100 copies of this file, Git has a single frozen copy that they all share.  It's quite safe to share the single copy because *no part of any commit can ever be changed* once the commit is made.

What this means in terms of *removing* a file is simple enough: the version control system needs to know that the *next* commit you make *shouldn't* have the file.  If commit #3 has the file, and commit #4 lacks the file, then obviously the file was removed between step 3 and step 4.

The complications in Git come in at many points here: first, while commits in Git *are* numbered, the numbers themselves are weird.  Each commit gets a *unique* number, and when I say unique, I don't mean "unique within some limit", I mean *unique*.  No Git commit, ever, anywhere, in any repository, has used the number before.  No future commit in any Git repository anywhere will ever use that number again!<sup>1</sup>  Git calls this "commit number" a *hash ID*,<sup>2</sup> and it's big and ugly and not suitable for human consumption, so aside from cut-and-paste with the mouse or whatever, we don't normally use these ourselves.

Still, that big ugly hash ID is the "true name" of each commit.  By giving that hash ID *to* Git, you can get back any older commit, including files you've "deleted".  So deleted files are still there in the *repository*.  But this gives us a couple of obvious problems:

- Committed files are stored in a weird, frozen, Gitty fashion.
- Only *Git* can *read* them and literally nothing, not even Git itself, can *overwrite* them.
- That means we can't get any work done.

All version control systems have this problem, and almost all of them use the same solution.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is [mathematically impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), of course, so it's not entirely true.  But if you bring together two unrelated Git repositories, and they've accidentally used the same number for two different commits, Git breaks.  [Ideally, this never happens, and in practice it doesn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

<sup>2</sup>Hash ID or Object ID (OID), really, and Git used to call this an *SHA1* as the existing hash function is SHA-1; see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)  As noted there, Git is slowly moving to SHA-256, hence the drive to stop using the term "SHA-1".

---

#### The "working tree"

In a commit-oriented system, you generally start by picking out some existing commit to *check out*, using some verb like *checkout* or *switch* or *extract*.  Git uses `git checkout` or `git switch`.<sup>2</sup>  The version control system then locates that commit, with all of its files, and *extracts* the files *from* the commit, into a work area.  Git calls this work area your *working tree* or *work-tree*.<sup>3</sup>  The commit you selected becomes your *current commit*, and in Git, the *branch name* you selected here becomes your *current branch name*.  (There is a whole lot of special Git weirdness here, too, that I'm omitting for length reasons.)

So, after a check-out operation (or `git switch` command), your working tree is now full of all the files, as of whatever form they had at the time you, or someone else, made the commit you've just chosen to use.  The files *in* your working tree are ordinary everyday files, usable by your ordinary everyday editor, your ordinary everyday Python or browser or whatever it is that uses them, and so on.  So now you can get work done!

It's important to realize that *these files are not in Git*.  They came *out* of Git just now, perhaps, but now that they *are* out, they're not "in".  As you work on and with these files, Git is not even aware of that.<sup>4</sup>  So when you're done messing with the files, it's important that you *tell Git*.  You do this with `git add` and `git rm`, but here's where things get *really* weird.  In other systems, like Mercurial, you use `hg rm` to remove a file, and you just use `hg commit` otherwise—no need to `hg add` all the time—because `hg commit` *figures out* what you changed.  This isn't true in Git.

---

<sup>2</sup>The `git switch` command was new in Git 2.23, the result of splitting up an overly-complicated `git checkout` into `git switch` and `git restore`.  You can now use either one of these, but if you have 2.23 or later, I recommend preferring `git switch` as it's *usually* less confusing (due to having the complications moved out to `git restore`).

<sup>3</sup>The OSes on which Git runs have the notion of a *current working directory* or `cwd`, often available with the `pwd` or Print Working Directory command or `$PWD` *shell variable*.  Git used to mix together the cwd and work-tree terms in ways people found confusing.  It can still be rather confusing, as Git uses the cwd to find the repository, which is stored in a hidden `.git` folder at the top level of the working tree.  This makes some things kind of upside down: the repository is stored *in* the working tree!  This is true even though the working tree is *not part of the repository*.

Git lets you peek inside the hidden folder if you like, though in general you should (a) not depend on its form and (b) not touch anything inside that folder.  Git is very sensitive about the files *in* this hidden folder, and cloud-syncing software such as Dropbox or iCloud *will* eventually corrupt the repository.  For this reason, it's unwise to store the working tree in a cloud-synced folder: the repository is inside the working tree, and is thus subject to this same sync, which breaks it.

<sup>4</sup>For speed reasons, modern Git is slowly acquiring a "file system monitor" setup that does make it somewhat aware of things happening here.  The design of this *must* take into account the fact that old Git doesn't have this, and that on most systems, such monitors can lose information sometimes, so except for making things go faster, the FSMonitor is *supposed* to act like it isn't even there.  If your system has the FSMonitor available—currently Windows and macOS do—and you turn it on and it misbehaves, just turn it off again.  Linux support is in the pipeline.

---

#### Git's *index* or *staging area*

As I just mentioned, other version control systems like Mercurial just have you run `hg commit`.  The command spends a bunch of time to figure out what you changed, in the working tree, and commits these changes.  (Mercurial uses a *changeset* model for its commits, rather than Git's *snapshot* model.)  Git is—different.  Git forces you to run `git add` every time.  Why?  The answer lies in this extra thing that Git has, which is messy and big and has three names:

- Git sometimes calls this *the index*, a sort of meaningless name.  I like to use this term as it covers everything it does, but it's not very memorable.
- Git sometimes calls this *the cache*, as a big part of its job is to make Git go fast.  (`hg commit` can take minutes but `git commit` usually finishes in a few milliseconds, and only some of that is due to `hg` being in Python and Git being compiled.  A lot of it is because of the index.)
- Last, in more modern documentation, Git calls this the *staging area*, which refers to how you normally use it: to *stage* what will go into the *next* commit.

What's in the index can be described, pretty accurately, this way: **The index holds your *proposed next commit snapshot*.**  That's it—that's the real key to the staging area, it's the *proposed next snapshot*—but that has a lot of consequence.

In particular, you now know (or should know) that the files *inside* any given commit are in some weird Git-ized format, not usable by non-Git software.  So are the files in Git's index.  The key difference between a *committed* copy of a file, and the *index* copy of a file, in Git, is that the *index* copy *can be replaced*.  (The committed copy is frozen forever.)

What *this* means in turn is simple as well: **You always have (up to) three copies of every "active" file.**  That is, suppose your existing commit has files `README.md` and `folder1/pyproject1.py`.<sup>5</sup>  Then there are actually *three copies* of `README.md` and *three copies* of `folder1/pyproject1.py`.

One of these "active copies" is the frozen, current-commit copy.  This copy *can't* be changed, as it's inside a commit.  Another is the *index* or *staging area* copy.  Initially, it's the same as the committed copy—and since Git's internal format is de-duplicated, it's been de-duplicated to literally use the original.  But you *can* replace this with a new copy: this doesn't overwrite the original, it just adds a new version of the file—or finds another existing duplicate to re-use—and prepares that for committing.  The third copy is the ordinary file, in your working tree.

The `git add` command means: *read the working tree copy and prepare it for committing, replacing the old index copy.*  The `git rm` command means: *remove both the index copy and the working tree copy.*

If you run `git add removedfile`, Git tries to read the working-tree copy of the removed file, and *then*, at that point, discovers that it's removed.  So `git add removedfile` notices that, hey, the file is gone, but it's still in Git's index.  Obviously you meant `git rm removedfile`!  Git removes the file from its index, and quietly does nothing about the already-removed file in the working tree, and that's how `git add` *can* mean `git rm`.

---

<sup>5</sup>Note that to Git, this is a *file named `folder1/pyproject1.py`.*  It's not a folder named `folder1` containing a file named `pyproject1.py`.  Git knows how to convert back and forth between the OS's requirement that files live in folders, and Git's requirement that things in the index have a single long file name with embedded forward slashes.  But in fact the index can *only* hold *files*, which means you can't store an empty folder in Git.  There is a trick or two here though: see [How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452)

---

#### OK, but then why didn't `git add *` work?

We now come to a point where Windows `CMD.EXE`, and just about every other command line interpreter in use these days, differ.

In Unix-like shells—bash, csh, sh, tcsh, zsh, and the like—it's the *shell*—the command line interpreter or CLI—that handles `*`.  You write:

```
*
```

or:

```
foo*
```

or:

```
folder1/*
```

and the *shell* finds *all files in the current directory* or *all files starting with `foo` in the current directory* or *all files in the `folder1/` folder* and expands out their names.<sup>6</sup>

If you have *removed* a file, `git add *` does not list it, because the *shell* expanded the `*` to the set of files that are here.  The removed file isn't here.  So it isn't listed!

On the ancient `CMD.EXE`, the CLI *does not* handle `*`.  This passes a literal asterisk to Git.  Because Git tries to accommodate these old systems, Git has its own globbing<sup>7</sup> code.  This code uses what's in Git's index, so here, `git add *` *will* add the removal of the file!

There is a whole lot more to this index, but I am trying to keep this answer relatively short.  If this seems like a lot of information, well, remember, a *good* Git tutorial will have covered all of this by now, and this should all be review to you.

---

<sup>6</sup>There's a subtle catch here, controllable in some shells but not all: a file whose name is `.hidden` *does not get found* by `*`, except in bash if you turn on `dotglob`:

```bash
$ shopt dotglob
dotglob         off
$ echo *
cover.html cover.out Makefile ...
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ echo *
.git .gitignore .golangci.yml cover.html cover.out Makefile ...
```

Most people normally keep `dotglob` off so that things like `.git` stay hidden.  But this means `git add *` won't add `.gitignore`, for instance.

<sup>7</sup>The expansion of `*` and other *glob characters* is referred to as *globbing*, and these characters are *called* glob characters, for [historical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).  Originally the shells didn't do this expansion themselves: they ran *another program* to do it.  Early versions of Unix ran in well under 64k of RAM, on computers that maxed out at 64k or sometimes 128k.  Think about that the next time you download a 50 megabyte app onto your 128 GB phone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm not sure I fully understand your solution. I know now that I can remove a file using `git rm myfile.png`, but I want to remove every file in the repository that has been deleted in my local folder automatically, as I have many files in my repository that are not in my local folder anymore. Is there a way to do that without having to check manually ?

Answer (score -1):

You will find one way to delete files from Git in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047477/13350995).

Anyway, if you delete a file on your local copy, commit and push it, it should be deleted on your remote too. Please try to use `git commit` without the message argument. This will open a text editor where you can see your changes (This is actually not the way to look at changes, but works very well in this case ;) and post a screenshot here.