# How do I reverse a specific hunk of a commit in git?

Tags: git, git-workflow

I'm wondering if there is a way to  quickly reverse  specific hunk of a commit.

I can generate a `diff` between two commits or `HEAD` to see the difference.

How do I reverse just one of those hunks (or better yet, a set of specific hunks)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
git checkout -p $REF -- path/to/file
```

e.g.,

```
git checkout -p HEAD^ myfile
```

Where `$REF` is a ref name or commit ID that specifies the commit you want to take the file state from.  For example, to selectively revert changes made in the last commit, use `HEAD^`.

Comment: More precisely, that will let you selectively check out versions of content from the previous commit; changes between your current commit and the work tree will also be discarded.

Comment: Yes I've done this that before. But this reverts back all the changes?  I'm looking to revert back only some of the changes.

Comment: @DKinzer: No, the `-p` option will let you interactively select hunks to apply to your working tree.

Comment: No problem.  Note that a lot of git commits (`add`, `checkout`, `reset`, etc.) will take the `-p` option this way and will let you pick which hunks to act on.  This is really handy when two hunks in the same file should go into different commits.

Comment: I'm new to git and so far only knew about -i for selectively choosing commits when doing a rebase.  I think the -p option will be very useful to me.

Comment: In order to remove hunks, select `y` when prompted for each hunk. This will produce a staged diff on top of your previous commit without modifying it.  You can then view the diff by unstaging it (`git reset <file>`) then `git diff`.  Finally, you can merge it into your previous commit via `git commit --amend <file>`).

Answer (score 3):

To revert one or more hunks from specific commit(s) do like this - using `add -p` in essence:

```
git revert --no-commit <commit>…​ 
git reset                              # unstage things
git add -p [OPTIONS] [<pathspec>…​]     # choose hunks interactively
git restore .                          # wipe the rest (in root directory)
... maybe further changes ...
git commit [--fixup] ...
```

Future git versions may support `git revert -p` directly...

Note: Methods like `git checkout/restore -p ...` do not consistently revert hunks from a specific commit but go to pick parts from a certain file state - possibly loosing changes in other later commits.

Answer (score 2):

```
git difftool $REF -- /path/to/file
```

where `$REF` is a ref name or commit ID that specifies the commit you want to take the file state from. For example, to selectively revert changes made in the last commit, use HEAD^.

This question was already answered by @cdhowie, but I find it somewhat nicer to use an interactive difftool like `meld` to selectively restore old hunks/lines of code, especially if there is a newly-introduced, hard-to-find bug in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To recover a deleted file from a previous commit I used the answer here:

[Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)

```
git checkout <deleting_commit>^ -- <file_path>
```