# Does git have (or need) the equivalent of svn's peg revision?

Tags: svn, git

Say I follow these steps in svn:

```
rev 1: create a file called 'foo'
rev 2: delete 'foo'
rev 3: create a new file called 'foo'
```

If I want to see the contents of the first '`foo`' using svn, I would need to use the peg revision syntax '`svn cat foo@1`' since the traditional syntax '`svn cat -r 1 foo`' would fail.
I've read that git tracks content and not files, so does that mean there's no need for something like a peg revision?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
git show HEAD~1:/path/tp/foo
```

will show you the content of the file as it was in "rev1" (note: you need to specify the full path of the file, from the root directory of the Git repo)

As mention in "[Restore a deleted file in a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo/1113140#1113140)", you can quickly restore a previous version of a file with a checkout.

```
git checkout $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- "$file")^ -- "$file"
```

(with `$file` being the full path of the file from the root directory of the current Git repo.)

Comment: Basically git always does the equivalent of `svn cat foo@1`. Linus would probably consider the behavior of `svn cat -r 1 foo` to be yet another one of svn's failures. (I do too)