# Git + Rails: How to restore files deleted with "git rm -r"?

Tags: git, git-rm

I deleted my db folder in a rails application in with git rm -r

I've tried

```
git reset HEAD
```

and

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

but the migration files arent coming back.  I tried commiting, then running the reset and still nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: Check here for an answer.  I believe it covers your situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can checkout the file from the commit where it still exists. Here's how to do it.

```
git checkout <commit where the file still exists> -- db
# Example:
git checkout 6936142 -- db

# This also works, but if you have a branch named the same as the file or path,
# it will throw an error.
git checkout 6936142 db
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `git reset --hard HEAD^1` (the commit just before HEAD). Or you can get the hash of a previous known working commit with `git log`, then `git reset --hard <hash>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout individual files from your last commit or index.

> `git checkout db/*` checks out everything under db from the index
>
> `git checkout master db/*` checks out everything under db from the head of the master branch

you may be able to salvage most of your stuff that way

read more: `git help checkout`