# Need to revert git rm done while working with master

Tags: git, github

I am working on master branch .
I used the following command.

```
git pull origin master

git rm <some files>

git commit -m "meesage"
git push origin master
```

I want to get back the file I deleted from the remote:( 
Please respond.

I tried :

```
git reset head 
git reset --hard head
```

Nothing worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git + Rails: How to restore files deleted with "git rm -r"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024288/git-rails-how-to-restore-files-deleted-with-git-rm-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it to go *back* 1 revision. One way to do that is to specify `HEAD~`:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

Without the tilde, you are just telling it to restore to the state since the most recent revision, which is the one that removed the file.

Comment: Hi that works locally. But when I try to pull and then push the code again from remote server . The pull again removes the files that were deleted. And yeah I cannot push these chanegs without a pull.

Comment: Yes, dealing with a remote server is another dimension. It's best to recover the files and then add them to a _new_ revision, and push that.

Comment: Yes you can push that to remote, you have to force it though. If a commit is in remote that is not in local, it typically means that someone else pushed a commit to the repo. Normally, you would then rebase your changes on top of that and push the result. In this case though, you have to tell git that you know what you are doing.

Comment: Concerning the advise to restore the file in a new commit, that's possible, too, it's just a `git revert REVISION` where `REVISION` is the commit you want to undo. However, assuming all users of the repo are smart enough to handle an upstream rebase (or to learn it), purging the faulty commit is probably the cleaner solution in this case. YMMV though.

Comment: I don't think changing the history is a good idea when others may be affected. That's why I suggest creating a new revision with the re-added files. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KeithBennett that helped me clear a lot of doubts .Thank you