# Commits for file in remote not showing in local repo

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

I have a git repository where the remote is hosted in TFS and when I look at the commits for a specific file there 5 commits on my dev branch. Locally i only see 3 commits on my dev branch. I've done a git pull and everything is up to date. How is this possible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Running a `git log`, do the commit hashes match in both? What are the names of the branches on remote and local? [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html) is a good TUI for git.

Comment: See images I added.

Comment: What does `git show --stat a1e1ff` show locally? Does it list any changes to that file?

Comment: Yes it shows changes to that file. 141 insertions, 132 deletions.

Comment: And how about `git branch -a --contains a1e1ff`? What about `git diff dev origin/dev`? I expect they are different between local and remote branches and for some reason the pull is not doing what you expect.

Comment: `$ git branch -a --contains a1e1ff` shows
* dev
  remotes/origin/dev

Comment: `$ git diff dev origin/dev` shows nothing

Comment: I suspect something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541321/how-does-a-commit-disappear-from-the-log-of-one-file. Try using `git log --full-history`.

Comment: @cmbuckley ahh that was it. They all show in --full-history