# Retrieving deleted files in git

Tags: git, github

I have folder of user data which I thought was .gitignored , however I was wrong and when I did a pull I got a conflict.

Currently, if I type "git status" I get a list of the files ( eg. "deleted: projects/tom/demo_project/1_2.mp3"), but they have actually been deleted.

Is it possible to recover this data?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo

Comment: @PhilipZaengle: the problem is different here, it's about a conflict with deleted files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming everything had previously been added to your local repository, you can use the `git reset --hard` command to restore your local repository to its state before your `git pull` command.

[This page](http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html) has more information than you'll ever want about the `reset` command.

Answer (score 0):

If the cuckoos might not have been added recently,

```
git log -a --oneline -- \*/cuckoos/glob/*
```

will show the commits that added or changed them, and

```
git log -a --source --decorate --ancestry-path --oneline --graph ^the-1st-of-them
```

will show everything that's been tainted -- with any luck, a short list all on your current branch.  If so, the reset will do you fine.  Otherwise you're headed for `filter-branch` territory.

Unless you've gone in and explicitly told git to get all draconian on your ass, git will forget *nothing* it has seen in the last 90 days, even things you added and then abandoned without ever committing.  You can reproduce and play mix-n-match with anything git has seen.