# How to sync the local folder with the Git Repository on NitrousIO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, nitrousio

First - I've created the git repository and also created the local repo of the same on my local system. 
Second - Worked on my local system and did some changes and pushed the changes on to the Git repository such that my local system source and git repository are in sync now

Now, Instead of working on my local system, I wanted to work on NitrousIO. Hence created the folder same as my git repository name and did `'git .init'` as well. Basically this is the `Ruby on Rails` application, hence followed `'rails new RKsJobs_Board'` to set up the folder and then `git .init`

**What I need is:**
As the remote git repository is up-to-date with the source code, I would like my NitrousIO folder to be in sync with the remote repository.

*How can I achieve this ?*

I tried this on Nitrous from the root directory like below:

```
action@rksrailszone-182221:~$ git checkout -- RKsJobs_Board                                                                                                                                           
error: pathspec 'RKsJobs_Board' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I also tried this on Nitrous from the actual directory like below:

```
action@rksrailszone-182221:~/RKsJobs_Board$ git checkout -- RKsJobs_Board                                                                                                                             
error: pathspec 'RKsJobs_Board' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I know something fishy is missing to get it work but unable to find out myself.

Let me know if you guys can help..

Comment: What is NitrousIO? What version of Git are you using on the different environments? What is `git .init`? (usually it is `git init .`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just did a `git init .`, the local git repo is empty and has no index for you to checkout.

You would need to add a remote repo url

```
git remote add origin /url/to/remote/repo
git fetch
git checkout master origin/master (or) git checkout master && git reset --hard origin/master
```

That would give you the content of the remote repo in your local repo history and working tree.

**Note -** Before following the steps, please ensure to have the empty folder then start with `git init .` and other steps mentioned above

Comment: NitrousIO is the cloud-based development environment platform with a web-based IDE. Yeah, it is git init and version is git version 2.0.0. BTW, I followed the steps but the last step is throwing this error 'error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.                                                                                                                                      
error: pathspec 'origin' did not match any file(s) known to git.'

Comment: @RamakishnaBalla what `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: origin  https://github.com/ramakb/RKsJobs_Board (fetch)                                                                                                                                               
origin  https://github.com/ramakb/RKsJobs_Board (push)

Comment: @RamakishnaBalla do you see the remote tracking branches like `origin/master` when you do a `git branch -avvv`? `git fetch` should have fetch the branches from `origin`.

Comment: When I did git branch -avvv --> this is what I got --remotes/origin/master a54473e Created basic Job flow successfully

Comment: @RamakishnaBalla can you try and reset your `master` branch to `origin/master` then? `git checkout master && git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: VonC - May I know your email-id as I still see error message and wanted to share that over email with more details...let me know otherwise...

Comment: @RamakishnaBalla that is better done over chat. I use stack Overflow to *not* receive emails ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69185/discussion-between-ramakishna-balla-and-vonc).