# How to reset repo using git?

Tags: git

I'm working with a repo that uses git. I ran `make depend` and it modified a bunch of recursive Makefiles. `git diff` shows an emdless list of changes, and I'd like to reset the repo.

Under SVN, I would simply delete the files (and directories) and `svn update` to re-check them out.

I tried to do the same according to [Restore a deleted file in a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo). Unfortunately, nothing was checked back out:

```
$ git reset HEAD; git checkout --
Unstaged changes after reset:
D   ACKNOWLEDGMENTS
D   CHANGES
D   CHANGES.SSLeay
D   Configure
D   FAQ
D   GitConfigure
...
$ ls
$
```

How do I reset this repo? Or is it easier to delete it and them re-check it out as if its a fresh checkout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Reset to `HEAD`:

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD
   ```
2. Clean out anything else left behind:

   ```
   git clean -fxd
   ```

Be warned that *both* of these commands can delete information and lose state.  Make sure to make a backup if you might lose something.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm not allowed to mark your answer yet, but I will when allowed.