# git: how to restore a file that has been deleted?

Tags: git, version-control

Here's what gives the latest diff

```
diff --git a/app/config/parameters.yml b/app/config/parameters.yml
deleted file mode 100755
index [not important]
--- a/app/config/parameters.yml
+++ /dev/null
```

With a comment comming with it: `git log`:

```
commit [not important]
Author: <not important>
Date:   [not important]

    Never commit the parameters.yml
```

And now git has deleted this file, which breaks the whole website. How to restore it?

This is not a duplicate because if I do this:

```
>git checkout [rev number not ipmortant] -- app/config/parameters.yml
error: pathspec 'app/config/parameters.yml' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So how comes **it's in the history**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If change is commited:

```
git checkout <commit hash> <filename>
```

If change is not committed, see [answer of WeGi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21134206/447249).

Also consider possibility of reverting the commit that deletes the file using git-revert, e.g.

```
git revert <commit hash>
```

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout filename` should restore the file, if the change is uncommited.

Also just found the question has allready been asked:
[Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)