# How to restore a file deleted by a commit?

Tags: git

I would like to restore a file that I deleted within a commit.  I tried

> git checkout path/to/deleted/file

but got

> error: pathspec 'path/to/deleted/file' did not match any file(s) known
>   to git.

How can I restore a file deleted by my latest commit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo

Comment: I'm no expert on git but it seems to me that you need to get a *previous* commit not the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

Also specify the last commit where the file was still present.

```
git checkout <commit> path/to/deleted/file
```

Comment: The previous commit, btw, is called HEAD~