# How to get deleted files from last commit?

Tags: git

I have folder with migrations. I accidentally deleted most of the migrations, only few left. How to restore only delete migrations from the last commit without overwriting current files ? Or just restore migration folder? I the could edit them once more. Folder is app/models.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore a deleted file in a Git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -- app/models` will revert any changes made to `app/models` since the last commit, including restoring the files you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you have several options:

- `git log --diff-filter=D --summary`
- checkout new branch and 'revert' the wrong commit. it will "return" all the deleted files
- use `git reflog` to return tot the desired point in time and create branch from this point
- use `git cat-file` to view the content of the commit and extract the date form the commit

to restore the deleted files: `git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --`