# Restore the files that are not added/commited

Tags: git

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    public/index.html
    deleted:    public/CSS/1.css
    deleted:    public/CSS/2.css
    deleted:    public/CSS/3.css
    deleted:    public/CSS/4.css
```

I accidentally removed files. How can I restore back them?

Comment: `git checkout public` is probably what you want.  I'm sure this question is a dupe, but I'm too lazy to look for the original.

Comment: "(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore a deleted folder in a Git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875205/restore-a-deleted-folder-in-a-git-repo)

Answer (score 1):

Just reset the working directory

```
git reset --hard
```

Or if there were other changes you could just checkout that directory

```
git checkout -- public/
```

Or if there were individual files you wanted to get back

```
git checkout -- public/<file>
```

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` or `git stash --all` might do as well

Answer (score 0):

To return public/index.html do

```
git ckeckout master public/index.html
```