# Recover deleted folder with Git after commit

Tags: git

I mistakenly deleted a folder and committed the change. How can I recover the folder?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Pedro Mesquita - Bem vindo. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875205/restore-a-deleted-folder-in-a-git-repo - possible duplicate

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout ****** folder
```

where ****** is a commit or a branch. This command put in current working directory the folder at the signed commit/branch.

For example, if you are in a particular branch you can run

```
git checkout master foo/bar
```

this will put in your current working directory the `foo/bar` that was present in master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to undo your last commit in git. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-last-commits-in-git) stackoverflow question should be what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you very much. Had to find the commit and merge the HEAD because it was detached. From there i had to add the folder again and managed to recover it.

Comment: No problem! Make sure to accept the answer. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the commit before you deleted the folder if you want to temporarily bring it back. If you want to permanently bring it back, you should probably revert your "bad" commit and then go from there.