# Did git checkout just delete my repository?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-commit, git-checkout

> **General Question:** How can one use Git locally alone (i.e. by oneself) in such a way that merging changes from a new branch into master, or moving from branch to branch using checkout, doesn't delete everything in the new branch and the master branch?
>
> Or if one wants to avoid git deleting everything and leaving no backups, is it essentially necessary to be working with a remote repository (e.g. GitHub), not just a local one?

**Specific Case:**
I had two branches for my local git repository, `master` and `equality`, located in the folder `.../ps/ps3`. I was in the branch `equality` and I wanted to merge my changes into `master`.

So first I did `git merge` and this returned the error:

`fatal: No remote for the current branch.`

So then I figured that I needed to be in `master` rather than `equality` to merge my changes from `equality` into master. So what I did next was: `git checkout master`. This produced the following error:

`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    ps3/ps3.aux
    ps3/ps3.log
    ps3/ps3.pdf
    ps3/ps3.synctex.gz
    ps3/ps3.tex
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting`

I interpreted that error as follows: nothing happened, I am still in the `equality` branch, I should make another commit of `equality` branch if I want my changes in `equality` to be saved when I use them to rewrite the `master` branch, rather than git rewriting from an earlier version of `equality`.

My terminal prompt indicated that I was still in the directory `.../ps/ps3` and in the branch `equality`, so I didn't think that anything was wrong. When I did `git commit -am "Finished correct proof"` I didn't get an error message.

`5 files changed, 155 insertions(+), 29 deletions(-)
 rewrite ps3/ps3.pdf (72%)`

> Now it was either this command, or the one immediately following it, which deleted *everything*, not just `equality` and every commit in that branch, but also `master` and every commit in the branch, and even the entire folder `.../ps/ps3` of the repository.

I did `git merge` (I was still in the branch `equality`) and I got the error message:

`fatal: No remote for the current branch.`

This confused me, because why would I need a remote of anything to do anything? And what did it have to do with my current situation? I guessed it was just an arcane way of complaining that merging the changes from `equality` into `master` needed to be done from `master`.

So next I did `git checkout master` and got no error, just `Switched to branch 'master'`. In spite of not getting any errors, I still think this may have been the step that deleted everything, since after doing this my terminal no longer showed that I was in either `equality` or `master`, so it seemingly must have at the very least deleted the entire repository, i.e. all of the files in it and the containing folder.

My terminal still said I was in a directory named `ps3` even though it didn't also list a git branch like it should have. So next I did `git merge` and then `git merge equality` but both returned the error:

`fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory`

Then I did `ls`, there was no output, then I did `cd ..` and `ls -a` and the directory `ps3` was not listed as being a subdirectory of `ps`. I.e. the containing folder for the repository, as well everything and every branch in it had been deleted somehow. I didn't even know it was possible to do this with Git -- I thought that the worst possible thing that could happen if I screwed up was that the earlier version in the `master` branch would overwrite the newer version in the `equality` branch, and that I could then just do `git revert` multiple times to get back the `equality` branch. And I thought `git checkout` just moved between branches, rather than deleting everything.

[This page](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/22) makes it seem like `git checkout master` does what I expected it to do, namely switch to the `master` branch, rather than deleting everything. Also [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875205/restore-a-deleted-folder-in-a-git-repo) makes it seem like `git checkout` should help restore files, so why did it delete all of mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, syntax: you're right that `git merge` needs to be run on the destination branch (and then you have to give it the name of the branch you want to bring in).

**What happened**: you were in a subdirectory of your working copy when you ran the `git checkout master`, and it removed that subdirectory because `master` didn't have any files there.  (The "unable to read current working directory" is what happens when you remove a directory while a shell is inside it.)

The **good news**: nothing is lost.  You're just still in the repository, rather than outside it looking at the space it once occupied.  Now is the time to run `git merge equality` and you'll see `ps3` come back.

The bad news: you committed your generated files (`.aux`, `.log`, etc.).  [Don't do that](https://perlmaven.com/dont-keep-generated-files-in-version-control); maybe you should go back to `equality` and `git commit --amend` them out of existence before you merge.  (It's a lot harder to fix nicely after you merge.)

Comment: Holy **** I want to marry you right now. This is amazing

Comment: To exclude the generated files, that would be putting `**/*.aux`,  `**/*.log`, etc. in a .gitignore file in the root directory of the repository?

Comment: Yes; you can leave out the `**/` when it's at the beginning.  That only affects new `add`s, though.  Removing them from your **current** commit (that you haven't **merged** yet!) is `git rm ps3/ps3.aux ...` and then the `--amend` I mentioned.